# Replace Fragment inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, view, android-fragments, android-viewpager, pager

I'm trying to use Fragment with a `ViewPager` using the `FragmentPagerAdapter`.
What I'm looking for to achieve is to replace a fragment, positioned on the first page of the `ViewPager`, with another one.

The pager is composed of two pages. The first one is the `FirstPagerFragment`, the second one is the `SecondPagerFragment`. Clicking on a button of the first page. I'd like to replace the `FirstPagerFragment` with the NextFragment.

There is my code below.

```
public class FragmentPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    static final int NUM_ITEMS = 2;

    MyAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }


    /**
     * Pager Adapter
     */
    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            if(position == 0) {
                return FirstPageFragment.newInstance();
            } else {
                return SecondPageFragment.newInstance();
            }

        }
    }


    /**
     * Second Page FRAGMENT
     */
    public static class SecondPageFragment extends Fragment {

        public static SecondPageFragment newInstance() {
            SecondPageFragment f = new SecondPageFragment();
            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //Log.d("DEBUG", "onCreateView");
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.second, container, false);

        }
    }

    /**
     * FIRST PAGE FRAGMENT
     */
    public static class FirstPageFragment extends Fragment {

        Button button;

        public static FirstPageFragment newInstance() {
            FirstPageFragment f = new FirstPageFragment();
            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //Log.d("DEBUG", "onCreateView");
            View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first, container, false);
            button = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                    trans.replace(R.id.first_fragment_root_id, NextFragment.newInstance());
                    trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    trans.addToBackStack(null);
                    trans.commit();

                }

            });

            return root;
        }

        /**
     * Next Page FRAGMENT in the First Page
     */
    public static class NextFragment extends Fragment {

        public static NextFragment newInstance() {
            NextFragment f = new NextFragment();
            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //Log.d("DEBUG", "onCreateView");
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.next, container, false);

        }
    }
}
```

**...and here the xml files**

`fragment_pager.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="4dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

`first.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/first_fragment_root_id"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <Button android:id="@+id/button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="to next"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now the problem... which ID should I use in

```
trans.replace(R.id.first_fragment_root_id, NextFragment.newInstance());
```

?

If I use `R.id.first_fragment_root_id`, the replacement works, but Hierarchy Viewer shows a strange behavior, as below.

At the beginning the situation is
[image]

after the replacement the situation is
[image]

As you can see there is something wrong, I expect to find the same state shown as in the first picture after I replace the fragment.

Comment: Did you generate that layout diagram somehow or did you manually do it?

Comment: @Noodles: I need to do the same. Your question has generated a long thread with many different answers. What worked best in the end? Many thanks!

Comment: @JeroenVannevel you might have figured it out already, but that layout diagram is https://developer.android.com/tools/performance/hierarchy-viewer/index.html

Comment: got some issue need your help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149039/viewpager-recyclerview-issue

Answer (score 167):

There is another solution that does not need modifying source code of `ViewPager` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, and it works with the `FragmentPagerAdapter` base class used by the author.

I'd like to start by answering the author's question about which ID he should use; it is ID of the container, i.e. ID of the view pager itself. However, as you probably noticed yourself, using that ID in your code causes nothing to happen. I will explain why:

First of all, to make `ViewPager` repopulate the pages, you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` that resides in the base class of your adapter.

Second, `ViewPager` uses the `getItemPosition()` abstract method to check which pages should be destroyed and which should be kept. The default implementation of this function always returns `POSITION_UNCHANGED`, which causes `ViewPager` to keep all current pages, and consequently not attaching your new page. Thus, to make fragment replacement work, `getItemPosition()` needs to be overridden in your adapter and must return `POSITION_NONE` when called with an old, to be hidden, fragment as argument.

This also means that your adapter always needs to be aware of which fragment that should be displayed in position 0, `FirstPageFragment` or `NextFragment`. One way of doing this is supplying a listener when creating `FirstPageFragment`, which will be called when it is time to switch fragments. I think this is a good thing though, to let your fragment adapter handle all fragment switches and calls to `ViewPager` and `FragmentManager`.

Third, `FragmentPagerAdapter` caches the used fragments by a name which is derived from the position, so if there was a fragment at position 0, it will not be replaced even though the class is new. There are two solutions, but the simplest is to use the `remove()` function of `FragmentTransaction`, which will remove its tag as well.

That was a lot of text, here is code that should work in your case:

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    static final int NUM_ITEMS = 2;
    private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private Fragment mFragmentAtPos0;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
        mFragmentManager = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        if (position == 0)
        {
            if (mFragmentAtPos0 == null)
            {
                mFragmentAtPos0 = FirstPageFragment.newInstance(new FirstPageFragmentListener()
                {
                    public void onSwitchToNextFragment()
                    {
                        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mFragmentAtPos0).commit();
                        mFragmentAtPos0 = NextFragment.newInstance();
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
            return mFragmentAtPos0;
        }
        else
            return SecondPageFragment.newInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object)
    {
        if (object instanceof FirstPageFragment && mFragmentAtPos0 instanceof NextFragment)
            return POSITION_NONE;
        return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
    }
}

public interface FirstPageFragmentListener
{
    void onSwitchToNextFragment();
}
```

Comment: works for me too, but how to implement back button to show the first fragment?

Comment: Great explanation but could you post full source code of this, specifically FirstPageFragment and SecondPageFragment classes.

Comment: I works for me as well, but I haven't been able to reverse the action, it's to say, and I think what @user1159819 means, once you are in NextFragment, you might want to go back to FirstFragment, I don't see how to do it with this implementation

Comment: If u want a more modular approach, i provided a more sophisticated solution which is based on wize's insights.

Comment: You can see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18612147/1088643). It replaces fragments and return back to first one.

Comment: I'm having hard time trying to use the [card flip animation](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html) with this. The animation does not work with `.remove()`, only with `replace()`, but using `replace` crashes the program - the replaced fragment animates away properly, but nothing animates in to replace it, leaving a blank black page in the view pager. Swiping to other pages works, but as soon as I return to the black page the app crashes. I wonder if I must override even more members of `FragmentPagerAdapter`?

Comment: Oh, and I have to use `Support.V13.App.FragmentPagerAdapter` as the adapter, because `Support.V4.App.FragmentPagerAdapter` does not allow native `Fragment`s, only the support fragments, and support fragments [crash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16734364/11683) on `objectAnimator` animation missing.

Comment: How do you add the FirstPageFragmentListener to the Bundle in newInstance() ?

Comment: Could you guys take a look at this question about ViewPager? Thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937250/viewpager-on-a-view-added-by-windowmanager-getting-java-lang-illegalargumentexc/27937559

Comment: what does mFragmentAtPos0  equate to?

Comment: Thanks - this was the simpliest implementation by far - worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, It worked like a charm. An alternate solution was to change it to FragmentStatePagerAdapter but above solution worked well with FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: Can you add the code where you handle with `FirstPageFragment.newInstance()` listener param?

Comment: I know this is an old question and answer but how would you do this in Xamarin android?

Comment: Please view my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519889/reload-data-on-tab-selected-on-fragment-using-view-pager

Comment: This only works for me if I call commitNow() instead of commit() when removing the fragment. Not sure why my use case is different, but hopefully this will save someone some time.

Comment: in my case i had to change from `FragmentPagerAdapter` to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and then it work

Comment: what if the fragment is like ```NextFragment.newInstance(item:Item)``` which ```item``` is set by an adapter?

Comment: @Ian Lovejoy thank you very much, it does the trick! I've spent couple of hours fighting with this issue until I see your suggestion about commitNow()

Answer (score 37):

As of November 13th 2012, repacing fragments in a ViewPager seems to have become a lot easier. Google released Android 4.2 with support for nested fragments, and it's also supported in the new [Android Support Library v11](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) so this will work all the way back to 1.6

It's very similiar to the normal way of replacing a fragment except you use getChildFragmentManager. It seems to work except the [nested fragment backstack isn't popped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706228/nested-fragments-and-the-back-stack) when the user clicks the back button. As per the solution in that linked question, you need to manually call the popBackStackImmediate() on the child manager of the fragment. So you need to override onBackPressed() of the ViewPager activity where you'll get the current fragment of the ViewPager and call getChildFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate() on it.

Getting the Fragment currently being displayed is a bit hacky as well, I used this [dirty "android:switcher:VIEWPAGER_ID:INDEX" solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7393477/467509) but you can also keep track of all fragments of the ViewPager yourself as explained in the second solution [on this page](http://tamsler.blogspot.nl/2011/11/android-viewpager-and-fragments-part-ii.html).

So here's my code for a ViewPager with 4 ListViews with a detail view shown in the ViewPager when the user clicks a row, and with the back button working. I tried to include just the relevant code for the sake of brevity so leave a comment if you want the full app uploaded to GitHub.

HomeActivity.java

```
 public class HomeActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
FragmentAdapter mAdapter;
ViewPager mPager;
TabPageIndicator mIndicator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
}

// This the important bit to make sure the back button works when you're nesting fragments. Very hacky, all it takes is some Google engineer to change that ViewPager view tag to break this in a future Android update.
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":"+mPager.getCurrentItem());
    if (fragment != null) // could be null if not instantiated yet
    {
        if (fragment.getView() != null) {
            // Pop the backstack on the ChildManager if there is any. If not, close this activity as normal.
            if (!fragment.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}

class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {        
    public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return ListProductsFragment.newInstance();
        case 1:
            return ListActiveSubstancesFragment.newInstance();
        case 2:
            return ListProductFunctionsFragment.newInstance();
        case 3:
            return ListCropsFragment.newInstance();
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

 }
}
```

ListProductsFragment.java

```
public class ListProductsFragment extends SherlockFragment {
private ListView list;

public static ListProductsFragment newInstance() {
    ListProductsFragment f = new ListProductsFragment();
    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);
    list = (ListView)V.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
          // This is important bit
          Fragment productDetailFragment = FragmentProductDetail.newInstance();
          FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
          transaction.addToBackStack(null);
          transaction.replace(R.id.products_list_linear, productDetailFragment).commit();
        }
      });       
    return V;
}
}
```

Comment: Will it be possible for you to upload your code to github? thanks.

Comment: @georgie plz, upload this sample project to github.

Comment: @georgiecasey: I tried your solution, but could not get the call to getChildFragmentManager() to resolve.  I am calling it from a click listener, similar to your example code.  The eclipse error message says "The method getChildFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MyFragment," where MyFragment is extended from SherlockFragment, just like your example.  What am I missing - any suggestions?

Comment: @georgiecasey: I downloaded API 17, Android 4.2 which allowed me to start using getChildFragmentManager().  But I must be missing something from your solution, as I am now getting overlapping old + new fragments on the screen.  Note: I'm trying to use your solution in concert with the Google example TabsAdapter code from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html.  Thanks for any suggestions and/or reference code.

Comment: What does R.id.products_list_linear refer to?  Please link to your code as was offered.

Comment: @howettl the ID references to outer fragment member. Key to solve this problem is to use nested fragments (that way you don't have to manipulate viewpager adapter).

Comment: TabPageIndicator mIndicator; what is this? please explain this

Comment: Is there any way to use child fragments manager with native `Fragment`s (as opposed to support fragments)? I'm using `Support.V13.App.FragmentPagerAdapter` to [feed native fragments to `ViewPager`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17556988/11683) because otherwise the [card flip animation is not availbale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723964/replace-fragment-inside-a-viewpager#comment35755987_9127423).

Comment: @gcl1 did you end up solving the issue you had? I am having the same issue with overlapping old/new fragments and I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: Did this ever make it to github?

Comment: georgiecasey I have problems with your solutions it kind of works however when the fragmets are replaced the button that replace the fragment is still visible on the screen. Do you happen to know how I can remove it

Answer (score 31):

Based on @wize 's answer, which I found helpful and elegant, I could achieve what I wanted partially, cause I wanted the cability to go back to the first Fragment once replaced. I achieved it bit modifying a bit his code.

This would be the FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final class CalendarPageListener implements
            CalendarPageFragmentListener {
        public void onSwitchToNextFragment() {
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mFragmentAtPos0)
                    .commit();
            if (mFragmentAtPos0 instanceof FirstFragment){
                mFragmentAtPos0 = NextFragment.newInstance(listener);
            }else{ // Instance of NextFragment
                mFragmentAtPos0 = FirstFragment.newInstance(listener);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    CalendarPageListener listener = new CalendarPageListener();;
    private Fragment mFragmentAtPos0;
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mFragmentManager = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof FirstFragment && mFragmentAtPos0 instanceof NextFragment)
            return POSITION_NONE;
        if (object instanceof NextFragment && mFragmentAtPos0 instanceof FirstFragment)
            return POSITION_NONE;
        return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
            return Portada.newInstance();
        if (position == 1) { // Position where you want to replace fragments
            if (mFragmentAtPos0 == null) {
                mFragmentAtPos0 = FirstFragment.newInstance(listener);
            }
            return mFragmentAtPos0;
        }
        if (position == 2)
            return Clasificacion.newInstance();
        if (position == 3)
            return Informacion.newInstance();

        return null;
    }
}

public interface CalendarPageFragmentListener {
    void onSwitchToNextFragment();
}
```

To perfom the replacement, simply define a static field, of the type `CalendarPageFragmentListener` and initialized through the `newInstance` methods of the corresponding fragments and call `FirstFragment.pageListener.onSwitchToNextFragment()` or `NextFragment.pageListener.onSwitchToNextFragment()` respictevely.

Comment: How do you perform the replacement? it isn't possible to initialize the Listener without overriding the onSwitchToNext method.

Comment: don't u lose the state saved in mFragmentAtPos0 if u rotate the device?

Comment: @seb, I actually improved this solution in order to save `mFragmentAtPos0` reference when saving the activity state. It's not the most elegant solution, but works.

Comment: You can see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18612147/1088643). It replaces fragments and return back to first one.

Comment: @mdelolmo Could you take a look at this question about ViewPager? Thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937250/viewpager-on-a-view-added-by-windowmanager-getting-java-lang-illegalargumentexc/27937559

Comment: Do we actually need to maintain the Fragment instance `mFragmentAtPos0`? Instead can we just save the `POSTION_NONE` or `POSITION_UNCHANGED`, which will notify the adapter. We can show what ever fragment we need in `getItem`. My thoughts.. Any suggestions? Any loop holes in implementing this way?

Comment: @ Ian Lovejoy, Use `commitNow()` save my time, `commit()` not work for me!

Answer (score 21):

I have implemented a solution for:

- Dynamic fragment replacement inside the tab
- Maintenance of the history per tab
- Working with orientation changes

The tricks to achieve this are the following:

- Use the notifyDataSetChanged() method to apply the fragment replacement
- Use the fragment manager only for back stage and no for fragament replacement
- Maintain the history using the memento pattern (stack)

The adapter code is the following:

```
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

/** The sherlock fragment activity. */
private final SherlockFragmentActivity mActivity;

/** The action bar. */
private final ActionBar mActionBar;

/** The pager. */
private final ViewPager mPager;

/** The tabs. */
private List<TabInfo> mTabs = new LinkedList<TabInfo>();

/** The total number of tabs. */
private int TOTAL_TABS;

private Map<Integer, Stack<TabInfo>> history = new HashMap<Integer, Stack<TabInfo>>();

/**
 * Creates a new instance.
 *
 * @param activity the activity
 * @param pager    the pager
 */
public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
    super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    this.mActivity = activity;
    this.mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
    this.mPager = pager;
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
}

/**
 * Adds the tab.
 *
 * @param image         the image
 * @param fragmentClass the class
 * @param args          the arguments
 */
public void addTab(final Drawable image, final Class fragmentClass, final Bundle args) {
    final TabInfo tabInfo = new TabInfo(fragmentClass, args);
    final ActionBar.Tab tab = mActionBar.newTab();
    tab.setTabListener(this);
    tab.setTag(tabInfo);
    tab.setIcon(image);

    mTabs.add(tabInfo);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
    final TabInfo tabInfo = mTabs.get(position);
    return Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, tabInfo.fragmentClass.getName(), tabInfo.args);
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(final Object object) {
    /* Get the current position. */
    int position = mActionBar.getSelectedTab().getPosition();

    /* The default value. */
    int pos = POSITION_NONE;
    if (history.get(position).isEmpty()) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    /* Checks if the object exists in current history. */
    for (Stack<TabInfo> stack : history.values()) {
        TabInfo c = stack.peek();
        if (c.fragmentClass.getName().equals(object.getClass().getName())) {
            pos = POSITION_UNCHANGED;
            break;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mTabs.size();
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(final ActionBar.Tab tab, final FragmentTransaction ft) {
    TabInfo tabInfo = (TabInfo) tab.getTag();
    for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
        if (mTabs.get(i).equals(tabInfo)) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(i);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

public void replace(final int position, final Class fragmentClass, final Bundle args) {
    /* Save the fragment to the history. */
    mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).commit();

    /* Update the tabs. */
    updateTabs(new TabInfo(fragmentClass, args), position);

    /* Updates the history. */
    history.get(position).push(new TabInfo(mTabs.get(position).fragmentClass, mTabs.get(position).args));

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * Updates the tabs.
 *
 * @param tabInfo
 *          the new tab info
 * @param position
 *          the position
 */
private void updateTabs(final TabInfo tabInfo, final int position) {
    mTabs.remove(position);
    mTabs.add(position, tabInfo);
    mActionBar.getTabAt(position).setTag(tabInfo);
}

/**
 * Creates the history using the current state.
 */
public void createHistory() {
    int position = 0;
    TOTAL_TABS = mTabs.size();
    for (TabInfo mTab : mTabs) {
        if (history.get(position) == null) {
            history.put(position, new Stack<TabInfo>());
        }
        history.get(position).push(new TabInfo(mTab.fragmentClass, mTab.args));
        position++;
    }
}

/**
 * Called on back
 */
public void back() {
    int position = mActionBar.getSelectedTab().getPosition();
    if (!historyIsEmpty(position)) {
        /* In case there is not any other item in the history, then finalize the activity. */
        if (isLastItemInHistory(position)) {
            mActivity.finish();
        }
        final TabInfo currentTabInfo = getPrevious(position);
        mTabs.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_TABS; i++) {
            if (i == position) {
                mTabs.add(new TabInfo(currentTabInfo.fragmentClass, currentTabInfo.args));
            } else {
                TabInfo otherTabInfo = history.get(i).peek();
                mTabs.add(new TabInfo(otherTabInfo.fragmentClass, otherTabInfo.args));
            }
        }
    }
    mActionBar.selectTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(position));
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * Returns if the history is empty.
 *
 * @param position
 *          the position
 * @return  the flag if empty
 */
private boolean historyIsEmpty(final int position) {
    return history == null || history.isEmpty() || history.get(position).isEmpty();
}

private boolean isLastItemInHistory(final int position) {
    return history.get(position).size() == 1;
}

/**
 * Returns the previous state by the position provided.
 *
 * @param position
 *          the position
 * @return  the tab info
 */
private TabInfo getPrevious(final int position) {
    TabInfo currentTabInfo = history.get(position).pop();
    if (!history.get(position).isEmpty()) {
        currentTabInfo = history.get(position).peek();
    }
    return currentTabInfo;
}

/** The tab info class */
private static class TabInfo {

    /** The fragment class. */
    public Class fragmentClass;

    /** The args.*/
    public Bundle args;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance.
     *
     * @param fragmentClass
     *          the fragment class
     * @param args
     *          the args
     */
    public TabInfo(Class fragmentClass, Bundle args) {
        this.fragmentClass = fragmentClass;
        this.args = args;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        return this.fragmentClass.getName().equals(o.getClass().getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return fragmentClass.getName() != null ? fragmentClass.getName().hashCode() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TabInfo{" +
                "fragmentClass=" + fragmentClass +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The very first time you add all tabs, we need to call the method createHistory(), to create the initial history

```
public void createHistory() {
    int position = 0;
    TOTAL_TABS = mTabs.size();
    for (TabInfo mTab : mTabs) {
        if (history.get(position) == null) {
            history.put(position, new Stack<TabInfo>());
        }
        history.get(position).push(new TabInfo(mTab.fragmentClass, mTab.args));
        position++;
    }
}
```

Every time you want to replace a fragment to a specific tab you call:
replace(final int position, final Class fragmentClass, final Bundle args)

```
/* Save the fragment to the history. */
    mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).commit();

    /* Update the tabs. */
    updateTabs(new TabInfo(fragmentClass, args), position);

    /* Updates the history. */
    history.get(position).push(new TabInfo(mTabs.get(position).fragmentClass, mTabs.get(position).args));

    notifyDataSetChanged();
```

On back pressed you need to call the back() method:

```
public void back() {
    int position = mActionBar.getSelectedTab().getPosition();
    if (!historyIsEmpty(position)) {
        /* In case there is not any other item in the history, then finalize the activity. */
        if (isLastItemInHistory(position)) {
            mActivity.finish();
        }
        final TabInfo currentTabInfo = getPrevious(position);
        mTabs.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_TABS; i++) {
            if (i == position) {
                mTabs.add(new TabInfo(currentTabInfo.fragmentClass, currentTabInfo.args));
            } else {
                TabInfo otherTabInfo = history.get(i).peek();
                mTabs.add(new TabInfo(otherTabInfo.fragmentClass, otherTabInfo.args));
            }
        }
    }
    mActionBar.selectTab(mActionBar.getTabAt(position));
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The solution works with sherlock action bar and with swipe gesture.

Comment: it's great! could you put it on the github?

Comment: This implementation is the cleanest of all of the provided here, and addresses every single issue. It should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Did anyone have issues with this implementation? I'm having 2 of them. 1. the first back doesn't register - I have to click back twice for it to register. 2. After I click back (twice) on tab a and I go to tab b, when I go back to tab a it just shows the content of tab b

Answer (score 7):

**tl;dr:** Use a host fragment that is responsible for replacing its hosted content and keeps track of a back navigation history (like in a browser).

As your use case consists of a fixed amount of tabs my solution works well: The idea is to fill the ViewPager with instances of a custom class `HostFragment`, that is able to replace its hosted content and keeps its own back navigation history. To replace the hosted fragment you make a call to the method `hostfragment.replaceFragment()`:

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackstack) {
    if (addToBackstack) {
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.hosted_fragment, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    } else {
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.hosted_fragment, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

All that method does is to replace the frame layout with the id `R.id.hosted_fragment` with the fragment provided to the method.

Check my [tutorial on this topic](https://medium.com/@nilan/separate-back-navigation-for-a-tabbed-view-pager-in-android-459859f607e4) for further details and a complete working example on GitHub!

Comment: Although this looks clumsier, I think is in fact the best (in terms of structure and ease of maintenance) way to do this.

Comment: I end up headbutting an NPE. :/ Can't find the View that is to be replaced

Answer (score 6):

To replace a fragment inside a `ViewPager` you can move source codes of `ViewPager`, `PagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` classes into your project and add following code.

into `ViewPager`:

```
public void notifyItemChanged(Object oldItem, Object newItem) {
    if (mItems != null) {
            for (ItemInfo itemInfo : mItems) {
                        if (itemInfo.object.equals(oldItem)) {
                                itemInfo.object = newItem;
                        }
                    }
       }
       invalidate();
    }
```

into FragmentStatePagerAdapter:

```
public void replaceFragmetns(ViewPager container, Fragment oldFragment, Fragment newFragment) {
       startUpdate(container);

       // remove old fragment

       if (mCurTransaction == null) {
            mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        }
       int position = getFragmentPosition(oldFragment);
        while (mSavedState.size() <= position) {
            mSavedState.add(null);
        }
        mSavedState.set(position, null);
        mFragments.set(position, null);

        mCurTransaction.remove(oldFragment);

        // add new fragment

        while (mFragments.size() <= position) {
            mFragments.add(null);
        }
        mFragments.set(position, newFragment);
        mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), newFragment);

       finishUpdate(container);

       // ensure getItem returns newFragemtn after calling handleGetItemInbalidated()
       handleGetItemInbalidated(container, oldFragment, newFragment);

       container.notifyItemChanged(oldFragment, newFragment);
    }

protected abstract void handleGetItemInbalidated(View container, Fragment oldFragment, Fragment newFragment);
protected abstract int  getFragmentPosition(Fragment fragment);
```

`handleGetItemInvalidated()` ensures that after next call of `getItem()` it return newFragment
`getFragmentPosition()` returns position of the fragment in your adapter.

Now, to replace fragments call

```
mAdapter.replaceFragmetns(mViewPager, oldFragment, newFragment);
```

If you interested in an example project ask me for the sources.

Comment: How should the methods getFragmentPosition() and handleGetItemInbalidated() be like?
I am unable to update getItem() to return NewFragment..
Please help..

Comment: Hi! Please find test project on this link http://files.mail.ru/eng?back=%2FEZU6G4

Comment: Your test project fails, if u rotate the device.

Comment: @AndroidTeamAtMail.Ru the link seems to expired.Will you please share the code

Comment: You can see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18612147/1088643). It replaces fragments and return back to first one.

Answer (score 6):

Some of the presented solutions helped me a lot to partially solve the problem but there is still one important thing missing in the solutions which has produced unexpected exceptions and black page content instead of fragment content in some cases.

The thing is that *FragmentPagerAdapter* class is using item ID to store cached fragments to *FragmentManager*. For this reason, you need to override also the *getItemId(int position)* method so that it returns e. g. *position* for top-level pages and *100 + position* for details pages. Otherwise the previously created top-level fragment would be returned from the cache instead of detail-level fragment.

Furthermore, I'm sharing here a complete example how to implement tabs-like activity with *Fragment* pages using *ViewPager* and tab buttons using *RadioGroup* that allows replacement of top-level pages with detailed pages and also supports back button. This implementation supports only one level of back stacking (item list - item details) but multi-level back stacking implementation is straightforward. This example works pretty well in normal cases except of it is throwing a *NullPointerException* in case when you switch to e. g. second page, change the fragment of the first page (while not visible) and return back to the first page. I'll post a solution to this issue once I'll figure it out:

```
public class TabsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  public static final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
  public static final int FIRST_PAGE = 0;
  public static final int SECOND_PAGE = 1;
  public static final int THIRD_PAGE = 2;

  /**
   * Opens a new inferior page at specified tab position and adds the current page into back
   * stack.
   */
  public void startPage(int position, Fragment content) {
    // Replace page adapter fragment at position.
    mPagerAdapter.start(position, content);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initialize basic layout.
    this.setContentView(R.layout.tabs_activity);

    // Add tab fragments to view pager.
    {
      // Create fragments adapter.
      mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(pager);
      ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.tabs_view_pager);
      pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

      // Update active tab in tab bar when page changes.
      pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int index, float value, int nextIndex) {
          // Not used.
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int index) {
          RadioGroup tabs_radio_group = (RadioGroup) TabsActivity.this.findViewById(
            R.id.tabs_radio_group);
          switch (index) {
            case 0: {
              tabs_radio_group.check(R.id.first_radio_button);
            }
            break;
            case 1: {
              tabs_radio_group.check(R.id.second_radio_button);
            }
            break;
            case 2: {
              tabs_radio_group.check(R.id.third_radio_button);
            }
            break;
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int index) {
          // Not used.
        }
      });
    }

    // Set "tabs" radio group on checked change listener that changes the displayed page.
    RadioGroup radio_group = (RadioGroup) this.findViewById(R.id.tabs_radio_group);
    radio_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int id) {
        // Get view pager representing tabs.
        ViewPager view_pager = (ViewPager) TabsActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.tabs_view_pager);
        if (view_pager == null) {
          return;
        }

        // Change the active page.
        switch (id) {
          case R.id.first_radio_button: {
            view_pager.setCurrentItem(FIRST_PAGE);
          }
          break;
          case R.id.second_radio_button: {
            view_pager.setCurrentItem(SECOND_PAGE);
          }
          break;
          case R.id.third_radio_button: {
            view_pager.setCurrentItem(THIRD_PAGE);
          }
          break;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!mPagerAdapter.back()) {
      super.onBackPressed();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Serves the fragments when paging.
   */
  private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public PagerAdapter(ViewPager container) {
      super(TabsActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager());

      mContainer = container;
      mFragmentManager = TabsActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();

      // Prepare "empty" list of fragments.
      mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>(){};
      mBackFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>(){};
      for (int i = 0; i < PAGE_COUNT; i++) {
        mFragments.add(null);
        mBackFragments.add(null);
      }
    }

    /**
     * Replaces the view pager fragment at specified position.
     */
    public void replace(int position, Fragment fragment) {
      // Get currently active fragment.
      Fragment old_fragment = mFragments.get(position);
      if (old_fragment == null) {
        return;
      }

      // Replace the fragment using transaction and in underlaying array list.
      // NOTE .addToBackStack(null) doesn't work
      this.startUpdate(mContainer);
      mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
        .remove(old_fragment).add(mContainer.getId(), fragment)
        .commit();
      mFragments.set(position, fragment);
      this.notifyDataSetChanged();
      this.finishUpdate(mContainer);
    }

    /**
     * Replaces the fragment at specified position and stores the current fragment to back stack
     * so it can be restored by #back().
     */
    public void start(int position, Fragment fragment) {
      // Remember current fragment.
      mBackFragments.set(position, mFragments.get(position));

      // Replace the displayed fragment.
      this.replace(position, fragment);
    }

    /**
     * Replaces the current fragment by fragment stored in back stack. Does nothing and returns
     * false if no fragment is back-stacked.
     */
    public boolean back() {
      int position = mContainer.getCurrentItem();
      Fragment fragment = mBackFragments.get(position);
      if (fragment == null) {
        // Nothing to go back.
        return false;
      }

      // Restore the remembered fragment and remove it from back fragments.
      this.replace(position, fragment);
      mBackFragments.set(position, null);
      return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns fragment of a page at specified position.
     */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      // If fragment not yet initialized, create its instance.
      if (mFragments.get(position) == null) {
        switch (position) {
          case FIRST_PAGE: {
            mFragments.set(FIRST_PAGE, new DefaultFirstFragment());
          }
          break;
          case SECOND_PAGE: {
            mFragments.set(SECOND_PAGE, new DefaultSecondFragment());
          }
          break;
          case THIRD_PAGE: {
            mFragments.set(THIRD_PAGE, new DefaultThirdFragment());
          }
          break;
        }
      }

      // Return fragment instance at requested position.
      return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    /**
     * Custom item ID resolution. Needed for proper page fragment caching.
     * @see FragmentPagerAdapter#getItemId(int).
     */
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      // Fragments from second level page hierarchy have their ID raised above 100. This is
      // important to FragmentPagerAdapter because it is caching fragments to FragmentManager with
      // this item ID key.
      Fragment item = mFragments.get(position);
      if (item != null) {
        if ((item instanceof NewFirstFragment) || (item instanceof NewSecondFragment) ||
          (item instanceof NewThirdFragment)) {
          return 100 + position;
        }
      }

      return position;
    }

    /**
     * Returns number of pages.
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object)
    {
      int position = POSITION_UNCHANGED;
      if ((object instanceof DefaultFirstFragment) || (object instanceof NewFirstFragment)) {
        if (object.getClass() != mFragments.get(FIRST_PAGE).getClass()) {
          position = POSITION_NONE;
        }
      }
      if ((object instanceof DefaultSecondragment) || (object instanceof NewSecondFragment)) {
        if (object.getClass() != mFragments.get(SECOND_PAGE).getClass()) {
          position = POSITION_NONE;
        }
      }
      if ((object instanceof DefaultThirdFragment) || (object instanceof NewThirdFragment)) {
        if (object.getClass() != mFragments.get(THIRD_PAGE).getClass()) {
          position = POSITION_NONE;
        }
      }
      return position;
    }

    private ViewPager mContainer;
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    /**
     * List of page fragments.
     */
    private List<Fragment> mFragments;

    /**
     * List of page fragments to return to in onBack();
     */
    private List<Fragment> mBackFragments;
  }

  /**
   * Tab fragments adapter.
   */
  private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, there is another problem whith this code. When I want to start an activity from fragment which was removed and added aggain, I get an error: "Failure saving state: active NewFirstFragment{405478a0} has cleared index: -1" (full stack trace: http://nopaste.info/547a23dfea.html). Looking to the android sources, I figure out that it has something to do with backstack but I don't know how to fix it so far. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Cool, using  <code>mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(old_fragment).attach(fragment).commit();</code> instead of <pre>mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).remove(old_fragment).add(mContainer.getId(), fragment).commit();</pre> in the example above seems to fix the both issues :-).

Comment: If you use this method, make sure you aren't letting Android recreate your Activity when rotating the device. Otherwise, the PagerAdapter will be re-created and you will lose your mBackFragments. This will also seriously confuse the FragmentManager. Using the BackStack avoids this problem, at the expense of a more complicated implementation of PagerAdapter (i.e. you can't inherit from FragmentPagerAdapter.)

Answer (score 6):

I have created a ViewPager with 3 elements and 2 sub elements for index 2 and 3 and here what I wanted to do..

[image]

I have implemented this with the help from previous questions and answers from StackOverFlow and here is the link.

[ViewPagerChildFragments](https://github.com/rukmaldias/ViewPagerChildFragments)

Comment: Your project fails, if you rotate the device.

Answer (score 4):

Works Great with AndroidTeam's solution, however I found that I needed the ability to go back much like `FrgmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)`  But merely adding this will only cause the Fragment to be replaced  without notifying the ViewPager. Combining the provided solution with this minor enhancement will allow you to return to the previous state by merely overriding the activity's `onBackPressed()` method. The biggest drawback is that it will only go back one at a time which may result in multiple back clicks

```
private ArrayList<Fragment> bFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
private ArrayList<Integer> bPosition = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void replaceFragmentsWithBackOut(ViewPager container, Fragment oldFragment, Fragment newFragment) {
    startUpdate(container);

    // remove old fragment

    if (mCurTransaction == null) {
         mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     }
    int position = getFragmentPosition(oldFragment);
     while (mSavedState.size() <= position) {
         mSavedState.add(null);
     }

     //Add Fragment to Back List
     bFragments.add(oldFragment);

     //Add Pager Position to Back List
     bPosition.add(position);

     mSavedState.set(position, null);
     mFragments.set(position, null);

     mCurTransaction.remove(oldFragment);

     // add new fragment

     while (mFragments.size() <= position) {
         mFragments.add(null);
     }
     mFragments.set(position, newFragment);
     mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), newFragment);

    finishUpdate(container);

    // ensure getItem returns newFragemtn after calling handleGetItemInbalidated()
    handleGetItemInvalidated(container, oldFragment, newFragment);

    container.notifyItemChanged(oldFragment, newFragment);
 }


public boolean popBackImmediate(ViewPager container){
    int bFragSize = bFragments.size();
    int bPosSize = bPosition.size();

    if(bFragSize>0 && bPosSize>0){
        if(bFragSize==bPosSize){
            int last = bFragSize-1;
            int position = bPosition.get(last);

            //Returns Fragment Currently at this position
            Fragment replacedFragment = mFragments.get(position);               
            Fragment originalFragment = bFragments.get(last);

            this.replaceFragments(container, replacedFragment, originalFragment);

            bPosition.remove(last);
            bFragments.remove(last);

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;       
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Also as far as `getFragmentPosition()` goes it's pretty much `getItem()` in reverse. You know which fragments go where, just make sure you return the correct position it will be in. Here's an example:

```
    @Override
    protected int getFragmentPosition(Fragment fragment) {
            if(fragment.equals(originalFragment1)){
                return 0;
            }
            if(fragment.equals(replacementFragment1)){
                return 0;
            }
            if(fragment.equals(Fragment2)){
                return 1;
            }
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `onCreateView` method, `container` is actually a `ViewPager` instance.

So, just calling

```
ViewPager vpViewPager = (ViewPager) container;
vpViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

will change current fragment in your `ViewPager`.

Comment: From hours of searching, it was this one line of code that I needed to make all my tabs work correctly.  `vpViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);`.  I went through each persons example, with nothing happening each time until I finally got to yours.  Thank you.

Comment: mind blown... this is amazing!! I did not realize that the container variable was the viewpager itself. This answer has to be explored first before all the other lengthy ones. Plus, there is no passing in of listener variables to the fragment constructor which simplifies all the implementation when Android auto-recreates fragments using the default no-arg constructor when config changes.

Comment: isn't this just changing to an existing tab? how is this related to replacing fragments?

Comment: Agree with @behelit, this does not answer the question, it will just move the `ViewPager` to another page, it won't replace any fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my relatively simple solution to this problem.  The keys to this solution are to use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter` as the former will remove unused fragments for you while the later still retains their instances.  The second is the use of `POSITION_NONE` in getItem().  I've used a simple List to keep track of my fragments.  My requirement was to replace the entire list of fragments at once with a new list, but the below could be easily modified to replace individual fragments:

```
public class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    private List<String> tabTitleList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragments(List<Fragment> fragments, List<String> titles) {
        fragmentList.clear();
        tabTitleList.clear();
        fragmentList.addAll(fragments);
        tabTitleList.addAll(titles);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        if (fragmentList.contains(object)) {
            return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
        }
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int item) {
        if (item >= fragmentList.size()) {
            return null;
        }
        return fragmentList.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also made a solution, which is working with **Stacks**. It's a more **modular** approach so u don't have to specify each Fragment and Detail Fragment in your `FragmentPagerAdapter`. It's build on top of the Example from ActionbarSherlock which derives if I'm right from the Google Demo App.

```
/**
 * This is a helper class that implements the management of tabs and all
 * details of connecting a ViewPager with associated TabHost.  It relies on a
 * trick.  Normally a tab host has a simple API for supplying a View or
 * Intent that each tab will show.  This is not sufficient for switching
 * between pages.  So instead we make the content part of the tab host
 * 0dp high (it is not shown) and the TabsAdapter supplies its own dummy
 * view to show as the tab content.  It listens to changes in tabs, and takes
 * care of switch to the correct paged in the ViewPager whenever the selected
 * tab changes.
 * 
 * Changed to support more Layers of fragments on each Tab.
 * by sebnapi (2012)
 * 
 */
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
        implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final TabHost mTabHost;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;

    private ArrayList<String> mTabTags = new ArrayList<String>();
    private HashMap<String, Stack<TabInfo>> mTabStackMap = new HashMap<String, Stack<TabInfo>>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        public final String tag;
        public final Class<?> clss;
        public Bundle args;

        TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            tag = _tag;
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
        private final Context mContext;

        public DummyTabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }
    }

    public interface SaveStateBundle{
        public Bundle onRemoveFragment(Bundle outState);
    }

    public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mTabHost = tabHost;
        mViewPager = pager;
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * Add a Tab which will have Fragment Stack. Add Fragments on this Stack by using
     * addFragment(FragmentManager fm, String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args)
     * The Stack will hold always the default Fragment u add here.
     * 
     * DON'T ADD Tabs with same tag, it's not beeing checked and results in unexpected
     * beahvior.
     * 
     * @param tabSpec
     * @param clss
     * @param args
     */
    public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args){
        Stack<TabInfo> tabStack = new Stack<TabInfo>();

        tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
        mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        String tag = tabSpec.getTag();
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);

        mTabTags.add(tag);                  // to know the position of the tab tag 
        tabStack.add(info);
        mTabStackMap.put(tag, tabStack);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * Will add the Fragment to Tab with the Tag _tag. Provide the Class of the Fragment
     * it will be instantiated by this object. Proivde _args for your Fragment.
     * 
     * @param fm
     * @param _tag
     * @param _class
     * @param _args
     */
    public void addFragment(FragmentManager fm, String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args){
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(_tag, _class, _args);
        Stack<TabInfo> tabStack = mTabStackMap.get(_tag);   
        Fragment frag = fm.findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + mViewPager.getId() + ":" + mTabTags.indexOf(_tag));
        if(frag instanceof SaveStateBundle){
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            ((SaveStateBundle) frag).onRemoveFragment(b);
            tabStack.peek().args = b;
        }
        tabStack.add(info);
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(frag).commit();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * Will pop the Fragment added to the Tab with the Tag _tag
     * 
     * @param fm
     * @param _tag
     * @return
     */
    public boolean popFragment(FragmentManager fm, String _tag){
        Stack<TabInfo> tabStack = mTabStackMap.get(_tag);   
        if(tabStack.size()>1){
            tabStack.pop();
            Fragment frag = fm.findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + mViewPager.getId() + ":" + mTabTags.indexOf(_tag));
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(frag).commit();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean back(FragmentManager fm) {
        int position = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
        return popFragment(fm, mTabTags.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabStackMap.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        ArrayList<Class<?>> positionNoneHack = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
        for(Stack<TabInfo> tabStack: mTabStackMap.values()){
            positionNoneHack.add(tabStack.peek().clss);
        }   // if the object class lies on top of our stacks, we return default
        if(positionNoneHack.contains(object.getClass())){
            return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
        }
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Stack<TabInfo> tabStack = mTabStackMap.get(mTabTags.get(position));
        TabInfo info = tabStack.peek();
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // Unfortunately when TabHost changes the current tab, it kindly
        // also takes care of putting focus on it when not in touch mode.
        // The jerk.
        // This hack tries to prevent this from pulling focus out of our
        // ViewPager.
        TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
        int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
        widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
        widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

}
```

Add this for **back button** functionality in your MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (!mTabsAdapter.back(getSupportFragmentManager())) {
    super.onBackPressed();
  }
}
```

If u like to **save the Fragment State** when it get's removed. Let your Fragment implement the interface `SaveStateBundle` return in the function a bundle with your save state. Get the bundle after instantiation by `this.getArguments()`.

You can **instantiate** a tab like this:

```
mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("firstTabTag").setIndicator("First Tab Title"),
                FirstFragmentActivity.FirstFragmentFragment.class, null);
```

works similiar if u want to add a Fragment on top of a Tab Stack. 
**Important**: I think, it won't work if u want to have 2 instances of same class on top of two Tabs.
I did this solution quick together, so I can only share it without providing any experience with it.

Comment: I get a nullpointer exception when pushing the back-button and my replaced fragment is not visible either. So maybe I am doing something wrong: what should be the correct call to change fragments properly?

Comment: Update: I got most of the stuff fixed, however, if I push a back-button after adding a new fragment and then go to another tab and back, I get a nullpointer exception. So I have 2 questions: 1: how can I remove the history of a tab and ensure only the latest fragment (top of te stack) is still present? 2: how can I get rid of the nullpointer exception?

Comment: @Jeroen 1: u can get the right stack from mTabStackMap, and then remove every TabInfo object that lies under the top of the stack, 2: very hard to say, ask a question with the stacktrace then i could try to find out, are u sure that's not a failure in your code? Does this happen also if u switch to a tab (and then back) that is in the direct neighborhood (right or left)?

Comment: Ok, I ran into a new problem: if I rotate my screen, then the stack seems to be empty again? It seems to loose track of the previous items...

Comment: @Jeroen: yes i ran into the same problem, but was expecting it, the activity gets recreated if u rotate the device this means your old variables are getting ate by the GB, the solution would be to save the stacks and tabinfos into the savestatebundle in the onDestroy method and then recover the tabsadapter state on recreations of the activity. Will do it some time, but atm to much to do on other stuff. There is also a quick dirty fix for rotating the device google it has to do with the manifest file.

Comment: @seb thanks. I was using this code but nested fragments are now possible so no longer a problem. :)

Comment: @Seb, I am using that hack, but this will get worse when the activity has lingered around for too long. I guess keeping the tabstacks and tabinfo's is the way to go.

Comment: @seb: If I would do it myself, then would it be wise to provide get'ers and set'ers of the tabstacks and tabinfo's at the tabsadapter and let the mainactivity save state in onPause and re-initialize the adapter at onResume?

Comment: @seb I am runnning into problems when I want to get your structure jsonified ;-), can you provide an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460200/gson-tojson-gives-stackoverflowerror-how-to-get-proper-json-in-this-case-publ#comment18420002_13460200 for me?

Comment: @Jeroen seems already solved. Feel free to ask if you have other probs.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing fragments in a viewpager is quite involved but is very possible and can look super slick. First, you need to let the viewpager itself handle the removing and adding of the fragments. What is happening is when you replace the fragment inside of SearchFragment, your viewpager retains its fragment views. So you end up with a blank page because the SearchFragment gets removed when you try to replace it.

The solution is to create a listener inside of your viewpager that will handle changes made outside of it so first add this code to the bottom of your adapter.

```
public interface nextFragmentListener {
    public void fragment0Changed(String newFragmentIdentification);
}
```

Then you need to create a private class in your viewpager that becomes a listener for when you want to change your fragment. For example you could add something like this. Notice that it implements the interface that was just created. So whenever you call this method, it will run the code inside of the class below.

```
private final class fragmentChangeListener implements nextFragmentListener {


    @Override
    public void fragment0Changed(String fragment) {
        //I will explain the purpose of fragment0 in a moment
        fragment0 = fragment;
        manager.beginTransaction().remove(fragAt0).commit();

        switch (fragment){
            case "searchFragment":
                fragAt0 = SearchFragment.newInstance(listener);
                break;
            case "searchResultFragment":
                fragAt0 = Fragment_Table.newInstance(listener);
                break;
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

There are two main things to point out here:

1. fragAt0 is a "flexible" fragment. It can take on whatever fragment type you give it. This allows it to become your best friend in changing the fragment at position 0 to the fragment you desire.
2. Notice the listeners that are placed in the 'newInstance(listener)constructor.  These are how you will callfragment0Changed(String newFragmentIdentification)`. The following code shows how you create the listener inside of your fragment.

   static nextFragmentListener listenerSearch;

   ```
       public static Fragment_Journals newInstance(nextFragmentListener listener){
               listenerSearch = listener;
               return new Fragment_Journals();
           }
   ```

You could call the change inside of your `onPostExecute`

```
private class SearchAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
        .
        .//some more operation
        .
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void param){

        listenerSearch.fragment0Changed("searchResultFragment");
    }

}
```

This would trigger the code inside of your viewpager to switch your fragment at position zero fragAt0 to become a new searchResultFragment. There are two more small pieces you would need to add to the viewpager before it became functional.

One would be in the getItem override method of the viewpager.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        //this is where it will "remember" which fragment you have just selected. the key is to set a static String fragment at the top of your page that will hold the position that you had just selected.  

        if(fragAt0 == null){

            switch(fragment0){
            case "searchFragment":
                fragAt0 = FragmentSearch.newInstance(listener);
                break;
            case "searchResultsFragment":
                fragAt0 = FragmentSearchResults.newInstance(listener);
                break;
            }
        }
        return fragAt0;
    case 1:
        // Games fragment activity
        return new CreateFragment();

    }
```

Now without this final piece you would still get a blank page. Kind of lame, but it is an essential part of the viewPager. You must override the getItemPosition method of the viewpager. Ordinarily this method will return POSITION_UNCHANGED which tells the viewpager to keep everything the same and so getItem will never get called to place the new fragment on the page. Here's an example of something you could do

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object)
{
    //object is the current fragment displayed at position 0.  
    if(object instanceof SearchFragment && fragAt0 instanceof SearchResultFragment){
        return POSITION_NONE;
    //this condition is for when you press back
    }else if{(object instanceof SearchResultFragment && fragAt0 instanceof SearchFragment){
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
        return POSITION_UNCHANGED
}
```

Like I said, the code gets very involved, but you basically have to create a custom adapter for your situation. The things I mentioned will make it possible to change the fragment. It will likely take a long time to soak everything in so I would be patient, but it will all make sense. It is totally worth taking the time because it can make a really slick looking application.

Here's the nugget for handling the back button. You put this inside your MainActivity

```
 public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        if(pagerAdapter.getItem(0) instanceof FragmentSearchResults){
            ((Fragment_Table) pagerAdapter.getItem(0)).backPressed();
        }else if (pagerAdapter.getItem(0) instanceof FragmentSearch) {
            finish();
        }
    }
```

You will need to create a method called backPressed() inside of FragmentSearchResults that calls fragment0changed. This in tandem with the code I showed before will handle pressing the back button. Good luck with your code to change the viewpager. It takes a lot of work, and as far as I have found, there aren't any quick adaptations. Like I said, you are basically creating a custom viewpager adapter, and letting it handle all of the necessary changes using listeners

Comment: Thank you for this solution. But have you had any problems after rotating screen. My app crashes when I rotate screen and trying to reload another fragment in the same tab.

Comment: Been a while since I've done Android dev, but my guess is that there is a piece of data that is no longer there your app is counting on. When you rotate, the whole activity restarts and can cause crashes if you try to reload your previous state without all the data you need (say from the bundle in onPause, onResume)

Answer (score 2):

This is my way to achieve that.

First of all add `Root_fragment` inside `viewPager` tab in which you want to implement button click `fragment` event. Example;

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
  if(position==0)
      return RootTabFragment.newInstance();
  else
      return SecondPagerFragment.newInstance();
}
```

First of all, `RootTabFragment` should be include `FragmentLayout` for fragment change.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/root_frame"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

Then, inside `RootTabFragment` `onCreateView`, implement `fragmentChange` for your `FirstPagerFragment`

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.root_frame, FirstPagerFragment.newInstance()).commit();
```

After that, implement `onClick` event for your button inside `FirstPagerFragment` and make fragment change like that again.

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.root_frame, NextFragment.newInstance()).commit();
```

Hope this will help you guy.

Comment: little bit late but still cant find easy solution.In your example when you rotate screen while in NextFragment app switches back to FirstPagerFragment...

Answer (score 1):

I found simple solution, which works fine even if you want add new fragments in the middle or replace current fragment. In my solution you should override `getItemId()` which should return unique id for each fragment. Not position as by default.

There is it:

```
public class DynamicPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<Page> mPages = new ArrayList<Page>();
private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

public DynamicPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public void replacePage(int position, Page page) {
    mPages.set(position, page);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void setPages(ArrayList<Page> pages) {
    mPages = pages;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (mPages.get(position).mPageType == PageType.FIRST) {
        return FirstFragment.newInstance(mPages.get(position));
    } else {
        return SecondFragment.newInstance(mPages.get(position));
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mPages.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // return unique id
    return mPages.get(position).getId();
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    while (mFragments.size() <= position) {
        mFragments.add(null);
    }
    mFragments.set(position, fragment);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    mFragments.set(position, null);
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    PagerFragment pagerFragment = (PagerFragment) object;
    Page page = pagerFragment.getPage();
    int position = mFragments.indexOf(pagerFragment);
    if (page.equals(mPages.get(position))) {
        return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
    } else {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
}
```

Notice: In this example `FirstFragment` and `SecondFragment` extends abstract class PageFragment, which has method `getPage()`.

Answer (score 1):

I doing something to similar to wize but in my answer yo can change between the two fragments whenever you want. And with the wize answer I have some problems when changing the orientation of the screen an things like that. This is the PagerAdapter looks like:

```
    public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    static final int NUM_ITEMS = 2;
    private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private Fragment mFragmentAtPos0;
     private Map<Integer, String> mFragmentTags;
     private boolean isNextFragment=false;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
        mFragmentManager = fm;
         mFragmentTags = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        if (position == 0)
        {


            if (isPager) {
                mFragmentAtPos0 = new FirstPageFragment();
            } else {
                mFragmentAtPos0 = new NextFragment();
            }
            return mFragmentAtPos0;
        }
        else
            return SecondPageFragment.newInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }


 @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Object obj = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        if (obj instanceof Fragment) {
            // record the fragment tag here.
            Fragment f = (Fragment) obj;
            String tag = f.getTag();
            mFragmentTags.put(position, tag);
        }
        return obj;
    }


    public void onChange(boolean isNextFragment) {

        if (mFragmentAtPos0 == null)
            mFragmentAtPos0 = getFragment(0);
        if (mFragmentAtPos0 != null)
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mFragmentAtPos0).commit();


        if (!isNextFragment) {
            mFragmentAtFlashcards = new FirstPageFragment();
        } else {
            mFragmentAtFlashcards = new NextFragment();
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object)
    {
        if (object instanceof FirstPageFragment && mFragmentAtPos0 instanceof NextFragment)
            return POSITION_NONE;
         if (object instanceof NextFragment && mFragmentAtPos0 instanceof FirstPageFragment)
            return POSITION_NONE;
        return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
    }


    public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
        String tag = mFragmentTags.get(position);
        if (tag == null)
            return null;
        return mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    }
}
```

The listener I implemented in the adapter container activity to put it to the fragment when attaching it, this is the activity:

```
    public class PagerContainerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ChangeFragmentListener {

//...

  @Override
    public void onChange(boolean isNextFragment) {
        if (pagerAdapter != null)
            pagerAdapter.onChange(isNextFragment);


    }

//...
}
```

Then in the fragment putting the listener when attach an calling it:

```
public class FirstPageFragment extends Fragment{


private ChangeFragmentListener changeFragmentListener;


//...
 @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        changeFragmentListener = ((PagerContainerActivity) activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        changeFragmentListener = null;
    }
//...
//in the on click to change the fragment
changeFragmentListener.onChange(true);
//...
}
```

And finally the listener:

```
public interface changeFragmentListener {

    void onChange(boolean isNextFragment);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed the answers by *@wize* and *@mdelolmo* and I got the solution. Thanks Tons. But, I tuned these solutions a little bit to improve the memory consumption.

Problems I observed:

They save the instance of `Fragment` which is replaced. In my case, it is a Fragment which holds `MapView` and I thought its costly. So, I am maintaining the `FragmentPagerPositionChanged (POSITION_NONE or POSITION_UNCHANGED)` instead of `Fragment` itself.

Here is my implementation.

```
  public static class DemoCollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private SwitchFragListener mSwitchFragListener;
    private Switch mToggle;
    private int pagerAdapterPosChanged = POSITION_UNCHANGED;
    private static final int TOGGLE_ENABLE_POS = 2;


    public DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Switch toggle) {
        super(fm);
        mToggle = toggle;

        mSwitchFragListener = new SwitchFragListener();
        mToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                mSwitchFragListener.onSwitchToNextFragment();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i)
        {
            case TOGGLE_ENABLE_POS:
                if(mToggle.isChecked())
                {
                    return TabReplaceFragment.getInstance();
                }else
                {
                    return DemoTab2Fragment.getInstance(i);
                }

            default:
                return DemoTabFragment.getInstance(i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Tab " + (position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

        //  This check make sures getItem() is called only for the required Fragment
        if (object instanceof TabReplaceFragment
                ||  object instanceof DemoTab2Fragment)
            return pagerAdapterPosChanged;

        return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
    }

    /**
     * Switch fragments Interface implementation
     */
    private final class SwitchFragListener implements
            SwitchFragInterface {

        SwitchFragListener() {}

        public void onSwitchToNextFragment() {

            pagerAdapterPosChanged = POSITION_NONE;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Interface to switch frags
     */
    private interface SwitchFragInterface{
        void onSwitchToNextFragment();
    }
}
```

Demo link here.. https://youtu.be/l_62uhKkLyM

For demo purpose, used 2 fragments `TabReplaceFragment` and `DemoTab2Fragment` at position two. In all the other cases I'm using `DemoTabFragment` instances.

Explanation:

I'm passing `Switch` from Activity to the `DemoCollectionPagerAdapter`. Based on the state of this switch we will display correct fragment. When the switch check is changed, I'm calling the `SwitchFragListener`'s `onSwitchToNextFragment` method, where I'm changing the value of `pagerAdapterPosChanged` variable to `POSITION_NONE`. Check out more about [POSITION_NONE](http://http:/https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getItemPosition(java.lang.Object)). This will invalidate the getItem and I have logics to instantiate the right fragment over there. Sorry, if the explanation is a bit messy.

Once again big thanks to @wize and @mdelolmo for the original idea.

Hope this is helpful. :)

Let me know if this implementation has any flaws. That will be greatly helpful for my project.

Answer (score 0):

after research i found solution with short code.
first of all create a public instance on fragment and just remove your fragment on onSaveInstanceState if fragment not recreating on orientation change.

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if (null != mCalFragment) {
        FragmentTransaction bt = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        bt.remove(mFragment);
        bt.commit();
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```