# How to correctly replace a fragment in a view pager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, actionbarsherlock

I have the following structure of my app:

```
v4 FragmentActivity --> v4 ViewPager --> v4 Fragment
                                     --> v4 ListFragment
```

I'm using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) (which I would really recommend), and the structure of the Activity is based on the demo at https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/app/ActionBarTabsPager.java . So the two fragments are displayed as two tabs for the user.

When a user clicks an element of the ListFragment I want to load an url in a WebView in the same place as the list is. That is, I want to replace the ListFragment (put it on the back stack) with a new WebView.

So far I've tried using [FragmentTransaction.replace()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) from the Activity. That kind of works, except two issues:

- The ListFragment doesn't display the WebView before I rotate the device (i.e. the acitity is recreated).
- The content of the other tab disappears (it's just blank)

What is the correct way to replace the ListFragment with another Fragment?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatevely, you could use a custom `HorizontalScrollView` instead of a `ViewPager` and overwrite its `onTouchEvent` method to get the same snapping effect  you get with a ViewPager, like this:

```
public class MyHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {

    public MyHorizontalScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }   

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (mScrollable) {
                        View child = getChildAt(0);
                        if (child != null) {
                            final int currentX = getScrollX();
                            final int windowWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                            final int totalWidth = child.getWidth();
                            int showingElementNumber = 1;
                            int i = windowWidth;
                            while (i < currentX && i < totalWidth) {
                                i+=windowWidth;
                                showingElementNumber++;
                            }

                            int scrollTo = 0;
                            if (currentX < (windowWidth * (showingElementNumber - 1) + windowWidth/2)) { // Previouses widths + half the current
                                scrollTo = windowWidth * (showingElementNumber - 1);
                            } else {
                                scrollTo = windowWidth * showingElementNumber + marginSize; 
                            }
                            smoothScrollTo(scrollTo, 0);
                            return false;

                        }
                    }
                    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            default:
                return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could add two `Fragments` inside it and use a regular `FragmentTransaction` with `addToBackStack()` to get what you want.

**NOTE:** If you want to use the above code, just make sure your Fragments are the same width as the entire screen and remember you structure should be something like

```
MyHorizontalScrollView > LinearLayout > YourFragment1
                                      > YourFragment2
```

Comment: I liked this solution. It was easy to implement and didn't mess up the code with workarounds. In this particular case I had some issues with scrolling sideways triggering link clicks in the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I've done what *AndroidTeam At Mail.Ru* and *connoisseur* suggest as answers on [Replace Fragment inside a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723964/replace-fragment-inside-a-viewpager). This is of course a pretty bad way solving this. I feel kinda dirty now. :-S