# Android - Backstack while replacing fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm creating ViewPager with three viewsin it. On the first view is a ListView, where onItemClick replaces that fragment new fragment with WebView in it. And I have two problems: when adding 'transaction.addToBackStack(null)', or 'transaction.setCustomAnimations(...)' Fragment with WebView stopps to show. Without these lines it shows, but I can't do BACK button to return to list.

I was creating code based on [that tutorial](http://tamsler.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-viewpager-and-fragments.html) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723964/replace-fragment-inside-a-viewpager). In that question there is used PagerAdapter, and I'm using FragmentPagerAdapter. Also I don't need more fragments to be replaced. It can be only once (from list to webView and back).

Here is my adapter's code:

```
public Fragment getItem( int position )
{
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch ( position )
    {
        case 0: // news
            if ( mFragmentAtPos0 == null )
            {
                mFragmentAtPos0 = new NewsListFragment( new FirstPageFragmentListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSwitchToNewsFragment( String url, ViewGroup container )
                    {
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                        transaction.setCustomAnimations( R.anim.rotate_in, R.anim.rotate_out, R.anim.rotate_in, R.anim.rotate_out );

                        WebViewFragment wv = new WebViewFragment( url, context );
                        transaction.replace( container.getId(), wv );
                        transaction.commit();

                        mFragmentAtPos0 = wv;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } );
            }
            fragment = mFragmentAtPos0;
            break;
        case 1: 
            fragment = new NewsInfoFragment( context, true );
            break;
        case 2: 
            fragment = new NewsInfoFragment( context, false );
            break;
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

and snippet from onCreateView() of that List's fragment:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id )
        {
            if ( position < listNewsAdapter.getCount() - 1 )
            {
                if ( listener != null )
                {
                    listener.onSwitchToNewsFragment( listNewsAdapter.getItem( position ).getNewsUrl(), container );
                }
            }
        }
    } );
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out my new answer to mentioned question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11974777/685292

You can see there an example how to implement simple back stacking with *ViewPager* by your own since *addToBackStack(null)* does not work for *ViewPager* fragments. Also note that main problem about your issue is probably the missing *getItemId(int position)* overriden method.

Answer (score 1):

**In new design support library, i use this solution** 
You can use stack to store the tabpositon by pushing the position in stack and getting back by using pop in stack.

In the main activity where there are 3 fragment in viewpager i create stack 
and push and pop data.

```
private Stack<Integer> stackkk;
private ViewPager mPager;
private int tabPosition = 0;



    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager);
    mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));
    mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tabPosition = tab.getPosition();
            mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            if (stackkk.empty())
                stackkk.push(0);

            if (stackkk.contains(tabPosition)) {
                stackkk.remove(stackkk.indexOf(tabPosition));
                stackkk.push(tabPosition);
            } else {
                stackkk.push(tabPosition);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tabPositionUnselected = tab.getPosition();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
}
```

and in the onBackPressed in activity,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (stackkk.size() > 1) {
        stackkk.pop();
        mPager.setCurrentItem(stackkk.lastElement());
    } else {
//do wat you want
    }
}
```

Hope this may help