# R.id.pager? Where is this defined?

Tags: android, android-layout

The example for viewpager, [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), contains the lines:

```
    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
```

I don't understand how R.id.pager is defined. Am I supposed to create a viewpager in xml somewhere? But that wouldn't make sense because it's instantiating a viewpager in the previous line. If someone could clear this up for me I would be most grateful!!

Thank you!!

**EDIT**

Apparently changing the line to:

```
mViewPager.setId(1);
```

Makes it work :) :)

Comment: have you tried `android.R.id.pager`?  if that doesn't work, then try this approach.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723964/replace-fragment-inside-a-viewpager.  If you want to know why, I can post an explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define the id directly in a resource file in the `res/values` directory. The name of the file is irrelevant, but it could look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item
        type="id"
        name="pager" />
</resources>
```

IDs can also spring up automatically in layouts when you set an id for a layout element using an attribute like this:

```
android:id="@+id/pager"
```

The `+` in the attribute says to add the indicated id to `R.id` if it isn't already there.

It's better to use an XML-defined ID rather than hard-coding a value into your code, for the same reason that it is better to use symbolic constants (e.g., `final static int FOO = 1;`) rather than sprinkling integer literals everywhere.

See [the docs on ID resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

It is defined in R.txt file under bin folder.

```
int id pager 0x7f05003c
```