# How to find an error when Logcat doesn't show any of your classes?

Tags: android, debugging, android-logcat

Developing my app with Android Studio, I'm having a runtime error but Logcat doesn't show the error in any of my classes.

How to determine where is the problem / what piece of code is failing when this happens?

Example:

```
09-17 13:29:23.420  17656-17656/com.mycompany.android.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:860)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:152)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1103)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2041)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7320)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2179)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1914)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1886)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1886)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1886)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1886)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1886)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1886)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2038)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1490)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2471)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1986)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7514)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3679)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3623)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4798)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4777)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4873)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:208)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:860) this is the problem

Comment: any idea how to solve it?

Comment: show the code where u setting the Visibility

Comment: NullPointerException means its getting null value

Comment: what IDE are you using? Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20893000/android-support-v4-app-fragment-setuservisiblehint-null-pointer-on-app-resuming

Comment: @zorpix I'm using Android Studio. Question edited.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I tried that solution before to ask. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I agree with Syed, that you should post the code where you're messing with visibility. My guess is you're trying to change visible properties of something that doesn't technically exist yet

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to encapsulate the code in your fragment within the isVisible() method. For example,

```
//do something
```

to

```
if(isVisible()) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: I'm already doing something like that. I've changed "getActivity!=null" for "isVisible()" because I feel it's an improvement of the code. Thanks for that.

Comment: I would like to add that I'm doing the stack trace of the app and seems that the error is in this piece of code.