# Check if fragment exists on Framelayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using ViewPager with 3 fragments in my project. One of these 3 fragments must contain another fragment inside of it, for what I have defined a FrameLayout in fragment's layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/valuesContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

        ...        
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/model3d_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/valuesContainer"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I add the new fragment programmatically:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_row3d, container, false);

        /*Check if fragment is already loaded*/
        Fragment frag = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.model3d_container);
        if (frag == null) {
            /*load fragment with 3d model*/
            Fragment modelFragment = new Obj3DView();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.model3d_container, modelFragment).commit();
        }
        return view;
    }
```

But when I navigate through the ViewPager's view, when I return to the fragment which contains the child fragment, the app crashes. Reading the Log, it seems that has something to do with the child fragment loading. I have defined a method to check if the fragment is loaded, and if so, not to load, but I think that is is reloading anyway.

```
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460): Process: com.rowingsoft, PID: 26460
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3759)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3612)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3557)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3533)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:931)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1884)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1514)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1280)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:672)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:244)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
10-13 12:48:34.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26460):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time trying to solve this issue, and looking for information about it, I finally found a way to make it work.

I realize that this is not the best solution, as this only fixes the problem, but doesn't solve it from the root.

Anyway, has make my app work, so here it is.

When defining the viewPager we set a limit of pages, that would be the number of pages we have. This, some way, avoids memory leaks and makes it work smooth. In one line:

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

This method is provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559353/how-to-solve-for-viewpager-the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `transaction.add` use `transaction.replace`

Comment: still crashes that way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```js
 /*Check if fragment is already loaded*/
        String tag = "myFrag";
        Fragment frag = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (frag == null) {
            /*load fragment with 3d model*/
            Fragment modelFragment = new Obj3DView();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.model3d_container, modelFragment, tag).commit();
        }
```

Finding by id works if in your XML you have a fragment, that id is not a fragment, instead its a FrameLayout.

Comment: also crashes that way.

Comment: Wait, didnt even notice that it's a frame layout not a fragment.

Going to edit the answer.

Comment: Even that way crashes. I think that this happens because it loads again the entire fragment, and is loading the view again, even if we check for the framelayout. Could be the solution to add the fragment in xml instead of programmatically?

Comment: Hmm, i need to recreate this, as far as I can tell there's nothing wrong with the code. In any case the best approach would be to override onDestroyView and remove the obj3DView fragment. That way when recreating the fragment there would be no issues.

Comment: I'm trying somethin like that. I'm going to remove the view before adding it, or as you say, in onDestroyView. But still I need to know how is removed