# Gson.toJson gives StackOverFlowError, how to get proper json in this case? (public static class)

Tags: java, android, json

I currently have the following class:

```
 static final class TabInfo{
   public final String tag;
   public final Class<?> clss;
   public Bundle args;

   TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
       tag = _tag;
       clss = _class;
       args = _args;
   }
 }
```

of which I would like to create json out of.
In order to do this, I am using the following code:

```
 Gson gson= new Gson();
 Type hmType= new TypeToken<TabInfo>(){}.getType();
 String json = gson.toJson(methodToGetAnInstanceOfTabInfoClassHere, hmType);
```

When I am doing this, I get a java.lang.StackOverFlowError:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at Java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:219)
E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:147)
E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:519)
E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:387)
E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beginObject(JsonWriter.java:300)
E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:190)
E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrap    E/AndroidRuntime(20692):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
```

So, my question is: how can I get my gson to create valid json of the java objects from class TabInfo without getting a stackoverflowerror?

Btw. as all of you can see, I have not asked that many questions before, so if you have any feedback for me on how to improve my question: let me know!

**EDIT 1:**
The bundle class is a standard bundle, fi:
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     args.putint("someint", 1);

See the updated stacktrace...

**EDIT 2:**
If I take a single instance of a TabInfo, by using a String.class as an argument, eg:

```
  TabInfo test= new TabInfo("test", String.class, new Bundle());
  String result=gson.toJson(test, hmType);
```

Then I get the following stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(22068): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: java.lang.String. Forgot to register a type adapter?
E/AndroidRuntime(22068):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:64)
E/AndroidRuntime(22068):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime(22068):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(22068):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
E/AndroidRuntime(22068):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
E/AndroidRuntime(22068):    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:586)
E/AndroidRuntime(22068):    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:565)
E/AndroidRuntime(22068):    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:520)
```

Does this mean that I need to make a TypeToken for all 24 different classes that might be part of a TabInfo class? How do I resolve this?

**Edit 3**

Ok, thanks to @Zaske, I have found a fix for the first part of my problem. Using another class signature as shown below

```
static final class TabInfo{
 TabInfo(String _tag, String _class, Bundle _args) {
   tag = _tag;
   clss = _class;
   args = _args;
 }

}
```

Now I can make json out of it, but, when I try to do this by creating the actual HashMap < String, < Stack < TabInfo > > > then again I run into trouble.
The typetoken i use in that case is:

```
 Type hmType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Stack<TabInfo>>>(){}.getType();
```

So, now my final question is: how can I convert a set of tabinfo-stacks in a hashmap to json?

**Edit 4**
Here's some more information:
The used Bundle class is the Bundle class used in Android to provide arguments to activities and fragments. (See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)

If I do

```
 TabInfo test= new TabInfo("test", "String", new Bundle());
 //stage 1 test
 String result=gson.toJson(test);
 Log.d("new result=",result);
```

Then I do get my Json output (see below)

```
 D/new result=(20816): {"args":{"mClassLoader":{"packages":{}},"mMap":{},"mHasFds":false,"mFdsKnown":true,"mAllowFds":true},"clss":"String","tag":"test"}
```

However, when I try to make a Hashmap of stacks out of the TabInfo classes, then it breaks (it runs out of memory...)...

Comment: Why are you passing class as parameter? I admit I am not a user of GSon, but passing Class<?> sounds strange to me. Why won't you pass a string representing the full class name?

Comment: Did you try to debug using gson sources?

Comment: Include more of the stack trace, and the definition of your Bundle class.

Comment: `StackOverflowException` is almost always due to infinite recursion, no?

Comment: @Zaske : I am using this class to keep track of the currently active classes in the different tabs of my application. So the type of class differs all the time.

Comment: @MiserableVariable: how can I debug using gson sources?

Comment: Do you know how to normally debug on Andorid? I am sure there is a lot of documentation available

Comment: @MiserableVariable Yes I do, but have not done so with Gson yet... Will look into it.

Comment: Can you please rewrite your class and change clss type to be String, and set in it the full class name of the class you want to hold?

Comment: @Zaske I have replaced the classname, will update the post with another edit...

Comment: @Zaske That is half my question answered :), if you can answer the other half as well, then my problem is solved and you should get the credits as an accepted answer:).

Comment: Why do you pass in second parameter to the `toJson` method?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev Because I have to tell gson what type it is.

Comment: @Jeroen: sorry to be too insisting in the matter but: why? As far as i can tell the problem with `Gson.toJson` needing type arraises only if the object you want to serialze is itself generic. Your case is not such as far as i can tell.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev You are right :). I just tested it and it works now without giving a type. But now, how do I extend this when using both a Stack and a Hashmap? because then I am working with generics right?

Comment: @Jeroen - do you manage to serialize at all? If so, paste a string containing the serialization. I suspect that GSon might have a problem with that, andy ou will need to write custom deserializer and serializer (I'm sure it can be done with Gson).

Comment: @Jeroen - Please see the sample I attached. for me it worked. I don;t know what Bundle class is, please provide more info, so I can try (I do not code for android - I use oracle/sun JDK)

Comment: @Zaske, I will update my question to provide more details :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested the "change from class" to string, 
 I allow myself for the sake of our readers to answer here for the first part: 
Don't use Class as a field, but use String that will contain the full class name 
TabInfo should look like:

```
static final class TabInfo{
   public final String tag;
   public final String clss;
   public Bundle args;

   TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
       tag = _tag;
       clss = _class.getName();
       args = _args;
   }
 }
```

Regarding 2nd part: 
I don't know what Bundle class is - please provide info, 
as I had to change a bit and write my own class for experiment.

Person class is:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public Person() {

    }

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

Main class for checking is:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String,Stack<Person>>>(){}.getType();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        HashMap<String,Stack<Person>> map = new HashMap<String, Stack<Person>>();
        map.put("yair", new Stack<Person>());
        map.get("yair").add(new Person("Yair",36));
        String str = gson.toJson(map,type);
        System.out.println(str);
        map = gson.fromJson(str,type);
        String str2 = gson.toJson(map,type);
        System.out.println(str2);

    }
}
```

Feel free to run it, you will see both str and str2 are printed just fine.

**Update**
I checked the Bundle class, and saw that it contains too much information (In my humble opinion) to be a simple arguments collection. 
I don't see why in the above question a simple collection cannot be used instead. 
Serialization should contain as minimal data as possible
 (think about cases in which you take a serialized data and store it on some storage device, or send it over the network).
So unless Bundle provides you a special functionality that a collection doesn't - don't use it. 
As a rule of thumb remember you cannot serialize everything with Json - there are limitations (recursive data-types for example) - so yes, there will be cases where you will have to translate from one type to a JSON-serializable type. 
This pattern is also used in other cases, I suggest you read more about [data transfer objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)

Comment: Then we have to debug and understand why. I don't have the source code of my example now, and it will take me some hours to get to it. Can you please update a stacktrace?

Comment: you mean a stacktrace of what goes wrong when I use your example?

Comment: Ok, I got my fatal exception: it hangs now on gson.fromJson(str, type), while using a "full bundle" (e.g.: I provided it with some arguments). It says:FATAL EXCEPTION: main: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke protected java.lang.ClassLoader() with no args at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$2.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:94) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:162) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)

Comment: The system out of str1= I/System.out(31370): {"yair":[{"args":{"mClassLoader":{"packages":{}},"mMap":{"this is an int":10,"String":"this is text","boolean":true},"mHasFds":false,"mFdsKnown":true,"mAllowFds":true},"clss":"String","tag":"test"}]} //here the mMap is the bundle of arguments with 3 pairs of a type and a value.

Comment: @Jeroen - why do you insist on using Bundle? It looks terribly wrong - it tries to serialize stuff like ClassLoader etc... this looks quite wrong.

Comment: @Jeroen - The error you received happens because upon deserializing all JSon Deserializes I know of will try to invoke a public empty CTOR. If you really insist on using Bundle, looks like you will have to write custom serializer and deserializer.

Comment: well alternatively I could make my own array of arguments that can be used to recreate a bundle, but that is not really a clean approach either right?

Comment: @Jeroen - way cleaner approach. Do you hold Paracable objects (whatever they are) at the Bundle? Doesn't look tike to me. So why abuse it, instead of using a simple map. Don't Serialize not-needed info (serializaion should contain minimal data as possible, for instance - think that you're going to send it over the web).)

Comment: I normally hold strings and ints at the Bundles. Android works that way (e.g.: it lets you work with the strings and ints). What I could do is take the arguments out of the bundle, serialize them, and at rebuild-phase de-serialize these arguments and put them back in their respective bundles...

Comment: @Jeroen - true. I recommend you do that. You can of course solve this also with Custom Serailizer and Deserializer that will manage this for you.

Comment: @Jeroen - so I think we're closed on this subject, right? :) I guess you can mark my answer is correct ;)

Comment: @zaske the Bundle is useful because you can pass it to the Fragement which gets instantiated from the information provided by the TabInfo Object, a Bundle can hold an other Bundle. So yes there is a need to write some recursive JSON. But I'm not shure if Jeroen needs this really, are you sending it to a server? If you are just saving on the sd card there are other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Another case that occurred to me was I was holding a **reference of Dialog in my Serialized class**.
While writing that class to preferences was throwing an exception.

The fix to avoid that is use of `transient` keyword to make a particular field non-serializable ([SO link for that particular solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687587/how-can-i-make-a-field-non-serializable-in-java)).

Example Code:

```
public class Player implements Serializable { 
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String slug;

    @Nullable
    transient Dialog prevDialogWeakRef;//non-serialised object

    // set getters()/setters()
}
```