# How can I make a field non-serializable in java?

Tags: java

Please, I need help with serializing data.

I have a class called Foo which defines 3 attributes:

```
    public int age;
    public String name;
    public String description;
```

How can I serialize this object, but without its description field?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make that field transient. Ex. public transient String description;

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use keyword `transient`:

```
public transient String description;
```

Comment: for followers, it's "OK' to mark a private variable transient as well `private transient String description` or the like

Answer (score 15):

define description as below

```
public transient String description;
```

check http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/transient

Answer (score 9):

You just need to make that one `transient`.

Example:

```
public transient String description;
```

Answer (score 7):

mark the variable as `transient`, as `Transient` variables are not serialized.

```
 public transient int age;
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometime it is required that some field we do not want to serialize during network stream.

```
Ex .
class userDetail{
  public String userName;
  public String password;
}
```

Here We do not want to serialize password.
Make that field as transient to remove from serilization.

```
Ex .
    class userDetail{
     public  String userName;
     public transient  String password;
    }
```