# When serializing an object, how can I prevent serialization of particular members?

Tags: java, serialization

I have a class that implements [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). When I serialize members of that class, there are certain variables/methods that I don't to want included in the serialized representation.

Consider a `Name` class that is `Serializable`:

```
class Name implements Serializable {
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;

    ...
}
```

Suppose I want the serialized form of each instance to exclude the `middleName` property.

Is there any way I can exclude particular properties and methods from being included in the serialized representation of the object?

Comment: I think this question was wrongly closed as "too broad", but I think *is* a duplicate of [How can I make a field non-serializable in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13687587)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a field non-serializable in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687587/how-can-i-make-a-field-non-serializable-in-java)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there any way i can achieve this?

**Yes** there is a method. You are looking for transient. Like this

```
private transient x;
```

To add to it all of object's variables which you have created get converted into a persistent state.  So when you declare those variables as transient then it will not be persisted. That is the main purpose of the transient keyword.

From the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.3):

> Variables may be marked transient to indicate that they are not part
>   of the persistent state of an object.

[Example from source](http://www.javabeat.net/what-is-transient-keyword-in-java/):

```
package javabeat.samples;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

class NameStore implements Serializable{
    private String firstName;
    private transient String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    public NameStore (String fName,
                         String mName,
                         String lName){
        this.firstName = fName;
        this.middleName = mName;
        this.lastName = lName;
    }
    public String toString(){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(40);
        sb.append("First Name : ");
        sb.append(this.firstName);
        sb.append("Middle Name : ");
        sb.append(this.middleName);
        sb.append("Last Name : ");
        sb.append(this.lastName);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
public class TransientExample{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        NameStore nameStore = new NameStore("Steve",
                                     "Middle","Jobs");
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream
                   (new FileOutputStream("nameStore"));
        // writing to object
        o.writeObject(nameStore);
        o.close();

        // reading from object
        ObjectInputStream in =new ObjectInputStream(
                new FileInputStream("nameStore"));
        NameStore nameStore1 = (NameStore)in.readObject();
        System.out.println(nameStore1);
    }
}
```

**// output will be :**

```
First Name : Steve
Middle Name : null
Last Name : Jobs
```

Answer (score 1):

Just define them as transient.

```
private String serializedField; // gets serialized
private transient String field; // doesn't get serialized
```

Answer (score 1):

transient keyword is used before variables whom you dont want to be serialized

eg.

```
private transient yourvariable;
```

and also transient cant be used with methods its for variables only

Answer (score 0):

To exclude members from being serialized define them as `transient`.

E.g.

```
public class A extends Serializable {
    private int a;
    private transient int b;
}
```

`b` will not be serialized in this class.

Answer (score 0):

Declare either transient or static before the data member to exclude serialization for that particular data members