# GSON: how to prevent StackOverflowError while keeping circular references?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I have a structure with circular references.
And for debug purposes, I want to dump it. Basically as any format, but I chose JSON.

Since it can be any class, I chose GSON which doesn't needs JAXB annotations.

But GSON hits the circular references and recurses until `StackOverflowError`.

How can I limit GSON to

- ignore certain class members?
  Both `@XmlTransient` and `@JsonIgnore` are not obeyed.
- ignore certain object graph paths? E.g. I could instruct GSON not to serialize `release.customFields.product`.
- go to the depth of at most 2 levels?

Related: [Gson.toJson gives StackOverFlowError, how to get proper json in this case? (public static class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460200/gson-tojson-gives-stackoverflowerror-how-to-get-proper-json-in-this-case-publ)

Comment: You might want to consider using Jackson for this. It has multiple methods for handling circular references and does not require JAXB annotations either.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Simply make the fields transient (as in `private transient int field = 4;`). GSON understands that.

**Edit**

No need for a built-in annotation; Gson lets you plug in your own strategies for excluding fields and classes. They cannot be based on a path or nesting level, but annotations and names are fine.

If I wanted to skip fields that are named "lastName" on class "my.model.Person", I could write an exclusion strategy like this:

```
class MyExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {

    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes fa) {                
        String className = fa.getDeclaringClass().getName();
        String fieldName = fa.getName();
        return 
            className.equals("my.model.Person")
                && fieldName.equals("lastName");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> type) {
        // never skips any class
        return false;
    }
}
```

I could also make my own annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface GsonRepellent {

}
```

And rewrite the `shouldSkipField` method as:

```
public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes fa) {
    return fa.getAnnotation(GsonRepellent.class) != null;
}
```

This would enable me to do things like:

```
public class Person {
    @GsonRepellent
    private String lastName = "Troscianko";

    // ...
```

To use a custom ExclusionStrategy, build Gson object using the builder:

```
Gson g = new GsonBuilder()
       .setExclusionStrategies(new MyOwnExclusionStrategy())
       .create();
```

Comment: Ok, but that will also affect Hibernate - the class is also an @Entity... no GSON specific annotation?

Comment: and since it seemingly did, how about accepting it...? pretty please? :-)

Comment: @OndraŽižka: no, really, I know that asking for rep is bad form - so feel free not to accept my answer or even vote id down (at least five other people found it useful). But I am really, really curious - what's wrong with it? Just a couple of words will do...

Comment: @OndraŽižka: it seems that you never accepted a single answer, except your own? Are there any special reasons?

Comment: @OndraŽižka: no, really, I don't even ask you to accept my answer any more. I would just like an answer for my last question from the comment above, if you were so kind?

Comment: this won't work well with ORMs in a case where transient filed is normally saved.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not accepting yet, I just didn't notice any of your comments until now. Seems you're spending quite some time checking who accepted what. I don't know currently if this would work as I don't have the project open now, so I can't responsibly accept in case it would not work. The answer is still here for others to try. I'll accept when I try, I promise.

Comment: @OndraŽižka: No, I don't spend any special time checking who accepted what - I just visit this answer every time it gets upvoted (like just now) and each time I am puzzled by the fact that a correct answer that got +18 votes is not accepted. Accepting an answer on SO is like saying: "thank you". Strange that someone would just say: "I don't care, whatever" - so I visited your profile and noticed that it's just the way you use SO.

Comment: @SaherAhwal Same as in Java, unless you have different requirements.

Comment: @fdreger it doesn't compile if I do it just like in Java

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has a few years now, but I'd like to contribute with my solution.
Although @fdreger's answer is completely valid in case you want to exclude a field **always**, it doesn't work if you want to exclude it just in certain cases, avoiding this way the recursion.
The way I approached the problem is:

1. I write my own `JsonSerializer`. In it, I define a static variable to control de number of times an object of this same class is serialize and depending on the value, the object can be serialized or not.

   ```
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class UserJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<User> {

        private static final ThreadLocal<Integer> depth = new ThreadLocal<Integer>() {
           @Override
           protected Integer initialValue() {
               return 0;
           }
        };

        @Override
        public void serialize(User user, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
           // Here, we limit the number of instances to return. In this case, just 1.

           depth.set(depth.get() + 1);
           if(depth.get() >= 1) {
               generator.writeNull();
           } else {
               generator.writeObject(user);
           }
        }

        public static void clear() {
           depth.remove();
        }
   }
   ```
2. Bind the `UserJsonSerializer` to the class you want to control

   ```
   public class SomeClass implements Serializable {
       @JsonSerialize(using = UserJsonSerializer.class)
       private User user;

      //...others fields...
   }
   ```
3. Don't forget to call `UserJsonSerializer#clear()` method to reinitialize the counter everytime you're going to parse a new entity.

I hope this helps.