# Eclipse and Google gson: how to show (nail down) the field that causes circular references?

Tags: eclipse, gson

I am doing a Java web project and have a few classes. They have circular references, some of which I do want to keep. However, when the json data of these classes is generated with gson, I get the following errors in Eclipse repeatedly until the stack is overflow.

I am using ExclusionStrategy ([GSON: how to prevent StackOverflowError while keeping circular references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489463/gson-how-to-prevent-stackoverflowerror-while-keeping-circular-references)) to exclude circular references from being exported into json, but the repetitive and endless error message does not show the field that causes the problem.

Thanks!

```
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
```