# StackOverflowError when using Gson with a JPA bean with join columns

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, gson

I have a Spring boot application where I'm using JPA to annotate my entities. I tried to use google GSON's api to serialize my models into json strings, but It's getting me a stackoverflowerror because of the circular references.

I've tried to declare this as transients, but then it throws me another error. Anyone knows a way to get Gson working with JPA annotated beans with circular references?

Contact class:

```
@Entity
public class Contact implements Serializable {

    /** Contact ID (will be the user ID) */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "User_Id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    /** User associated with the contact data */
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "User_Id", nullable = false)
    private User userDB;

// some more fields, getters and setters.
}
```

User class:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userDB")
    private Contact contact;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489463/gson-how-to-prevent-stackoverflowerror-while-keeping-circular-references