# HashMap in HashMap Java

Tags: java, json, hashmap, gson

I would like to serialise this to a `JSON` string:

```
private Map<Variant, Map<Integer, ItemStack>> inventorySorting;
```

I tried to use `new TypeToken<Map<Variant, Map<Integer, ItemStack>>>(){}.getType()));`
But i got this exception: 
[image]

Comment: It looks like you have circular references between your objects. You need to add to your question how thew two classes are implemented. See: [GSON: how to prevent StackOverflowError while keeping circular references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489463/gson-how-to-prevent-stackoverflowerror-while-keeping-circular-references) and [How to solve circular reference in json serializer caused by hibernate bidirectional mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340485/how-to-solve-circular-reference-in-json-serializer-caused-by-hibernate-bidirecti)

Comment: Please add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)