# replace fragments inside fragment displayed by the viewpager

Tags: android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-listfragment, android-fragmentactivity

Please see the wireframe image https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OnJ2.png first.

I am using a ViewPager to display fragments inside a FragmentActivity. ViewPager gets fragments from the attached FragmentPagerAdapter

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);       
mAdapter = new HomePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());    
mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Suppose viewpager has 3 fragments to display say Fragment1, Fragment2, Fragment3.
In the above image 'displaying fragment1' is the title for the first fragment, "Fragment1". This fragment is a list fragment and displays a list. Fragment2 and Fragment3 have their own content to display. when the user swipes on the screen, ViewPager will display the next fragment, "Fragment2".

What i want is that, when an item from the list(displayed by Fragment1) is clicked, Fragment1 should be completely replaced with some other Fragment, say Fragment4 (this is different fragment and is not returned by the attached adapter). when Fragment4 is displayed, the actionbar should change its content. whenever user works on Fragment4 and onBackPress or an action from the ActionBar, Fragment1 with the list should be displayed again. Meanwhile ViewPager should behave the same i.e on swipe, and the next fragment(in our case Fragment2) will be displayed.

basically, i want to get the same behavior as in example at :

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace

In this example the ListFragment is displayed directly inside a FragmentActivity. I am displaying the ListFragment with a ViewPager. I want the same functionality from the above example but inside fragments displayed with ViewPager. This was very difficult to achieve before the release of Android 4.2. this version of android supports nested fragments using `getChildFragmentManager()` so, i see some hope.

I am trying this on my side for many days and also scanned entire stackoverflow for Q & A related to nested fragments but didn't get what i want.

So, is this possible to achieve? if yes, then how to?

Answer (score 1):

This was a big problem before Android 4.2 but it seems to easier now with nested fragments, apart from ensuring the back button works. I posted my solution to your question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13925130/467509

My solution answers everything you asked apart from changing the ActionBar.