# Replacing a fragment in a view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying find a solution simular this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13925130/1634451 but the poster didn't explain what R.id.products_list_linear is. I tried to set R.id.products_list_linear as the id of my linearlayout for the fragment i am trying to replace. But that just overlays the 2 fragments on top of each other. I am pretty sure that i need to get the id of the container in the viewpager but i don't know how to get this id.

Edit:
To clarify i am trying to replace a fragment in a view pager with another my code looks almost exactly like the answer I posted but when I make R.id.products_list_linear the I'd of the fragment I am trying to replace layout. The fragment I am replacing just gets overlaid on the one I am trying to replace

Comment: You're trying to "switch" fragments in your view pager, right? 

Also, your question is a little bit vague. You'll receive better answers if you provide a little bit more context, any errors you're receiving/ specific problems, and maybe even some applicable code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a different approach that worked out nicely for me. I used a ViewSwitcher for the fragment in the viewpager.

Answer (score 2):

**Replace Fragments Within a View Pager**

Try this customized ViewPager Adapter,..

```
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments=null;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager=null;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager,List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    this.fragments=fragments;
    this.fragmentManager=fragmentManager;
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}
@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
{
    super.setPrimaryItem(container,0,object);
}
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged()
{
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    fragmentManager.saveFragmentInstanceState(fragments.get(position));
}
public void replaceItem(int position,Fragment fragment)
{
    fragments.set(position, fragment);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

call it from activity with fragment as arguments,

```
List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment1.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment2.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment3.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment4.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment5.class.getName()));
mPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), fragments);
```

When you replace view/fragment inside of viewPager then use,

```
mPagerAdapter.replaceItem(2,Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment5.class.getName()));
```

Comment: How does this help me replace a fragment in the viewpager? Can you show me the code to do that? tried 
fragments.set(0, Fragment.instantiate(this,   ReplacementFragment.class.getName()));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I have edited the code including viewpager adapter, that is works fine. So check this and reply must. Thanks for trying...