# Android replace Fragment inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I search a possibility to replace a fragment in a Tab stored in a ViewPager.
I read the answers of this question [Replace Fragment inside a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7723964/1069981)

One Answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13925130/1069981) contains a solution based on nested fragments that are supported since Android 4.2.
But this answer seems not to be the right solution. An existing Fragment will not be replaced by another. A new fragment will be added (nested) to the existing fragment. Or I am misunderstanding something?

Now I want to know if I there is a possibility to replace a fragment based on this answer or what is the best solution of the many answers?

Comment: Have you found any solution?