# Replace fragment in ActionBar Tabs that have swipe view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I did a quick search in here and didn't find any answers for my qustion, if its already answered please point me to that question ..

I have an ActionBar Tabs with swipe views implemented according to this [android training](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging). My activity have 3 tabs
`Weather` `Comment` `Dashboard`
and these fragments
`WeatherFragment` `CommentsFragment` `LoginFragment` `DasboardFragment` `RegisterFragment`

As the activity is started,
`Weather Tab` displays `WeatherFragment` , 
`Comments Tab` displays `CommentsFragment` and 
`Dashboard Tab` displays `LoginFragment`

If Login is successful in `LoginFragment`, `DasboardFragment` should replace the `LoginFragment` inside the `Dashboard` Tab. So if user swipes to other tabs and come back to `Dashboard Tab` `DasboardFragment` should be visible.

I'm new to android development, so any code snippets or tutorial would be greatly appreciated

Code i've so far **MainActivity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_network_weather);

    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    //actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    //actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {                      
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {         
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }       
}

public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            return new WeatherInfoFragment();
        case 1:
            return new PostsFragment();
        default: //TODO method to find which fragment to display ?
            return new LoginFragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return "Weather";
        } else if (position == 1){
            return "Comments";
        }
        else{
            return "Dashboard";
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
 }
 }
```

**LoginFragment**

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements AsyncResponse {
Button loginButton;
TextView loginError, login_url;
JSONfunctions task;
JSONObject jsonObject;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    loginButton = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button_login);
    loginError = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.login_error);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            attemptLogin(finalLoginUrl);
            // attemptPost(postURL);
        }
    });
}

private void attemptLogin(String url) {     
        try {
            task = new JSONfunctions(getActivity());
            task.listener = this;
            task.execute(new String[] { url });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("attempt login", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void processFinish(String result) {
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        int success = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("Success"));
        if (success == 0) {             
            // Replace LoginFragment and launch DashboardFragment ?                 
        } else {
            loginError.setText(jsonObject.getString("ErrorMessage"));
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON parsing from login result", e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was my own fault for not reading the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12155594/2235914) thoroughly. Implemented the code from that answer and got the functionality working :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the best way to handle this but you could define a static boolean inside your `MainActivity` like so:

```
public static boolean loggedIn = false;
```

(e.g. below `ViewPager mViewPager;`)

And then, in your method `processFinish(...)` inside the `LoginFragment` when `success` is `0` just set `MainActivity.loggedIn = true;`

This way you can simply put in an if-statement inside your default-case in getItem-method to check whether the user is logged in (if so call the Dashboard-Fragment) or not (display Login-Fragment).

Hope this works for you!

**Edit: LoginFragment**

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements AsyncResponse {
Button loginButton;
TextView loginError, login_url;
JSONfunctions task;
JSONObject jsonObject;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    loginButton = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button_login);
    loginError = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.login_error);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            attemptLogin(finalLoginUrl);
            // attemptPost(postURL);
        }
    });
}

private void attemptLogin(String url) {     
    try {
        task = new JSONfunctions(getActivity());
        task.listener = this;
        task.execute(new String[] { url });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("attempt login", ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void processFinish(String result) {
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        int success = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("Success"));
        if (success == 0) {             
            MainActivity.loggedIn = true;                 
        } else {
            loginError.setText(jsonObject.getString("ErrorMessage"));
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON parsing from login result", e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried it out but didn't work :( Think i need to implement some sort of callback method to the my AppSectionsPagerAdapter. I found a similar question here [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723964/replace-fragment-inside-a-viewpager/

Comment: But i keeping getting error when trying to implement it to my code. Would like to see the fragments code from that answer .. any suggetions .. ?

Comment: I edited the answer and put in the code of the Login-Fragment, was that what you wished for? `if (success==0)` is where I inserted the code.
And what error do you get?

Comment: i meant fragments code from the this  answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723964/replace-fragment-inside-a-viewpager?answertab=votes#tab-top  btw the i don't get any error but the login fragment doesn't change even after successful login.

Comment: Have you tried implementing the code from that link? Please share your code once you've done, because right now I can't imagine where you want to include this code into yours.

Comment: I managed to get the solution working, was my own fault. I din't read the answer from the link clearly enough. I used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12155594/2235914) answer from this  [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723964/replace-fragment-inside-a-viewpager?)