# Fragment : Unknown animation name objectanimator

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, objectanimator

I'm trying to do a flipping card animation between two fragment like in --> [Displaying Card Flip Animations](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html) by using:

```
private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();

        if ((fragment != null) && !(fragment.equals(currentFragment))) {

            if (transactionByMenu) {
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                        android.R.anim.fade_out);
            } else {
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(
                        R.animator.card_flip_right_in,
                        R.animator.card_flip_right_out);
            }

            Fragment nextFragment = fragment;
            fragmentTransaction.hide(currentFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.show(nextFragment);

            currentFragment = nextFragment;
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

The transaction in `if(transactionByMenu){...}` works but not in `else{...}`

I'd check my libs and stuff and i'm currently target higher than `api 11` but I still have this error message:

```
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: objectAnimator
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:124)
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:114)
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:91)
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:72)
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.loadAnimation(FragmentManager.java:710)
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.hideFragment(FragmentManager.java:1187)
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:610)
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-22 11:32:34.706: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="package.stage.stackoverflow"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="2.0.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="package.stage.stackoverflow.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="package.stage.stackoverflow.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/SampleTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="package.stage.stackoverflow.MyFragmentActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my Key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It's been two day I'am stuck with this, thank you in advance.

Comment: can you please try custom animation instead of android.R.anim.fade_in and fade_out

Comment: Oh sorry i edited my it didn't Copy/paste the right instruction. Actually it is `fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(
   R.animator.card_flip_left_in,
   R.animator.card_flip_left_out);`

Comment: can you add full code for fragment transaction ?

Comment: Edit done : The transaction in `if(transactionByMenu){...}` works but not in `else{...}`

Comment: I think issue is on your animator.card_flip_right_in, can you please code of that too, Generally we add animations in anim folder and access them using R.anim.animation_name

Comment: I used the same XML as in the --> [Displaying Card Flip Animations](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I believe you are trying to use objectAnimator in support fragments library, but it was added in Android Api level 11.

Comment: then you should use getFragmentManager instead of getSupportFragmentManager.

Comment: Ok so i can't use it with support fragment or Sherlock on 11 that's it ?

Comment: If your app target minSDKVersion - 11, then there is no need to use getSupportFragmentManager, because getFragmentManager() can be used and then you can also use objectAnimator.

Comment: and what if i want to use it with Support Library ?

Comment: then you can not use ObjectAnimator, so you'll have to create the flip animation in a different way, simple as that :)

Comment: Thank you very for this answer, I figured it in another way : [THERE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WGnB-hXUFk)

Comment: @GlennSonna Can you let us know what is the other way which worked for you?

Comment: The Tutorial you posted under "THERE" isn't about the problem. Until yet there is no solution for this question!

Answer (score 17):

If you declared your object animation in an xml file, be sure to put it into the **animator** folder and not the **anim** folder to tell android to use the new animation framework.

Here from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#declaring-xml) :

> To distinguish animation files that use the new property animation APIs from those that use the legacy view animation framework, starting with Android 3.1, **you should save the XML files for property animations in the res/animator/ directory (instead of res/anim/)**. Using the animator directory name is optional, but necessary if you want to use the layout editor tools in the Eclipse ADT plugin (ADT 11.0.0+), because ADT only searches the res/animator/ directory for property animation resources.

Answer (score 3):

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left,R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
                ProductOverview commentFragment = new ProductOverview();
                commentFragment.setArguments(b);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.product_container, commentFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: What is `commentFragment.setArguments(b);` ? I can't use the replace I need to keep all of my Fragments's states, that's why I rather use show/hide.

Comment: Using setArguments you can attach a Bundle and then in your fragment you can call getArguments to retrieve any values you attach to the bundle. This is a useful way of passing certain types of information into a fragment when creating a new instance.