# android Fragment Transaction

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
                .commit();
```

I wrote this code for adding animation during transaction. this create the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: objectAnimator
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: objectAnimator
         at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:126)
         at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:93)
         at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:74)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fragment : Unknown animation name objectanimator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688900/fragment-unknown-animation-name-objectanimator)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to use `objectAnimator` in support fragments library, but it was added in Android Api level 11.

Use

```
getFragmentManager()
```

instead of

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
```

If you declared your object animation in an xml file, be sure to put it into the animator folder and not the anim folder to tell android to use the new animation framework.

Support fragment manager does not support animators (only animations). Exception message says that you have wrong format of animation in your xml resource, probably because you have moved animator to this xml which is wrong (because they have different notation). You need to write it in proper way: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

I hope it helps!