# What is the equivalent of android.R.id.content for replacing a ViewPager with a single fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

With a regular activity, you can use

```
// Display the fragment as the main content.
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
             .commit();
```

to replace your main content with another fragment. With the default swipable tabs activity in Eclipse, this just overlays your new fragment on top of the other fragments. Can I get the id of the entire ViewPager somehow and replace that instead of android.R.id.content? I want to replace all of the tabs with my new fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally fragments are inflated in FrameLayout
for eg;- fragment_layout.xml

```
<FrameLayout android:id"@+id/framelayout" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

In fragment class we set this layout as contentVIew as follows:

```
public class TestFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);
```

}

And we can put any fragments in this content frame Layout using replace() method in Activity:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .replace(R.id.framelayout, new NewFragment())
             .commit();
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and I'm pretty sure it's the correct answer. It doesn't actually work in the default Eclipse swipable tabs activity (the new fragment doesn't display), but I think that's probably due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723964/replace-fragment-inside-a-viewpager/11974777#11974777 . I don't have time to deal with that right now.