# How to replace Fragment inside ViewPager, using PagerAdapter?

Tags: android, replace, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

### My problem

I am using a `ViewPager` to display fragments inside a `FragmentActivity`. ViewPager gets fragments from the attached `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);       
mAdapter = new HomePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());    
mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Suppose `ViewPager` has 3 fragments to display: `Fragment1`, `Fragment2`, `Fragment3`. `Fragment1` is a grid fragment and displays a grid. `Fragment2` and `Fragment3` have their own content to display. 
When the use swipes on the screen, `ViewPager` will display the next fragment - `Fragment2`. And so on.

### What I want?

What I want is that, when an item from the grid (displayed by `Fragment1`) is clicked, `Fragment1` should be completely replaced with some other fragment, say `Fragment4` (this is different fragment and is not returned by the attached adapter). User will work on `Fragment4` and after `ButtonBack` click (just button iside `Fragment4`), `Fragment1` with the grid should be displayed again. Meanwhile `ViewPager` should behave the same i.e on swipe, the next fragment (in our case `Fragment2`) will be displayed.

So I just want to get the same behavior as in example:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace

### My question

So, is this possible to achieve? If yes, then how to?
I would greatly appreciate for your help. Alex.
P.S. Sorry for my English:)

Comment: Look [this][1]. It is a solution in this case.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723964/replace-fragment-inside-a-viewpager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by adding another `FragmentActivity` that displays your `Fragment4`. Use `Intent` to start this activity and sent grid item position or other data in `Extra`.

On press of backbutton this activity will be finished and last activity with view pager will be displayed.

[EDIT] Old response. Better solutions are provided in other answers,

Answer (score 17):

I've made a little example that shows how to achieve it:

https://github.com/danilao/fragments-viewpager-example

I think the point is to use another fragment as a container.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do the fragment transaction and add the existing fragment into backstack.
I created a sample project to show you how to do it.

The code is not fine tuned, I just created it to show you how to do it.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxHClVwHSqq5dVRvT1Qyd0hYN0k&usp=sharing

But please be aware that even if you press back at any of the view pager screen, the previous fragment ends up showing as it is the same activity.

IF this is not expected behavior, then you should consider having multiple activities instead ( like tab layout )