# understanding Fragment replacement using FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

I'm having a hard time understanding how to replace `fragment`s using the `FragmentPagerAdapter`. I have a class that extends `FragmentPagerAdapter` (`android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`) and my `MainActivity implements ActionBar`.`TabListener`, in the `FragmentPageAdapter` class I use the `getItem()` to setup my 3 `fragment`s. so far so good.

One of these `fragment`s is a `ListView` (pos #1), which I use a Listener to check on the `onItemClick()`.

I want to replace the current `ListView` `Fragment` with another `fragment` so what I did is that inside the `onItemClick()` I perform the following code:

```
FragmentManager mFragmentManager = mActivity.getFragmentManager();          

//new fragment to replace
Fragment mFragment = new TabPlaceFragment();

mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.pager, mFragment)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
```

What this is doing is that *the fragment is replace with a blank `fragment`, I'm assuming is the pager, but the `mFragment` does not get replace. I tried giving an Id to the Current `fragment` and tried replacing it.*

```
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.frament_old, mFragment)
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .commit();
```

But what this does is that it overlaps the new `fragment` on top of the old `fragment`

finally I tried getting the Id of the `fragment` to replace with the new, but this also gave me a blank `fragment`.

```
//this gives me the current fragment I want to replace
    Fragment mCurrent = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(MainHelper.getFragmentName(mViewPager.getId(), 1));


    mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(mCurrent.getId(), mFragment)
                                    .addToBackStack(null)
                                    .commit();
```

I'm sure I'm not implementing the method correctly but I cannot find a good example to follow the logic of my code. I thought of putting the fragment replacement in the `MainActivity` under `getItem()`, but don't know how to call it from within my `onItemClick()` Listener.

Any help is highly appreciated!!!

Thanks.

Comment: after `commit` call `viewpager.getAdapter().notifayDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Thank you @mmlooloo, it does make perfect sense that the `mViewPager` needs to notify of a change made, sadly in my code it didn't work, I still got the two fragment overlapping each other. In the past I've worked with `FrameLayout` in the xml and replament works great, right now I'm not (I'm following example from Google and the code generated by Eclipse). I will play around with the `FrameLayout` but I think I need to understand better how the `ViewPager` works and interacts with the `FragmentManager`.

Comment: i suggest you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745600/how-to-replace-fragment-inside-viewpager-using-pageradapter and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445437/replace-fragment-with-another-fragment-inside-viewpager and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588944/replace-one-fragment-with-another-in-viewpager and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723964/replace-fragment-inside-a-viewpager

Comment: Thanks again @mmlooloo! the example in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745600/how-to-replace-fragment-inside-viewpager-using-pageradapter) did help understand, as expected I need a `FrameLayout` to host my fragments, which I wasn't doing. I will give it a try.

Comment: also `POSITION_UNCHANHED` and `POSITION_NONE`

Comment: Thanks @mmlooloo! the sample code you referenced worked great! I understand it now how to replace fragments within the `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Comment: for me was following this example: [link](https://github.com/danilao/fragments-viewpager-example) I was missing a `FrameLayout` to host the new Fragments.