# View Pager Android - Change Item

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have the following viewpager adapter.

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        /** Constructor of the class */
        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        /** This method will be invoked when a page is requested to create */
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
            switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                return new CreateLeague();
            case 1:
                return new JoinLeague();
            case 2:
                return new LeagueList();
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }

        /** Returns the number of pages */
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }
```

I have a button in first fragment (Here `CreateLeague()`) and on taping that button, I want to change the view pager item to third one. `viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);` But this is another fragment and I can't access the viewpager object there. Is there any right way to do this?

Comment: fragment transaction will get the job done

Comment: @IllegalArgument: You mean to replace the fragment? Then that is not possible in my case. I have a pager_indicator. So I must go with the viewpager transition.

Comment: see this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723964/replace-fragment-inside-a-viewpager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BroadcastReceiver.

If you are not familiar with BroadcastReceiver, you can view [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html).

Comment: Yeah, I think BroadcastReceiver should be the easiest way to solve this problem.

Comment: Used broadcast receiver and it solved my problem. Thank you @daimajja:

Comment: Congratulation！ @SreejithSP

Answer (score 1):

You can define an interface in the Fragment class and implement it within the Activity. The fragment alerts the activity when the button is clicked and then activity changes the current item. It's explained [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: Thank You. Let me try this.