# Dynamic inner Fragment in ViewPager overlapping

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

Hi I've pseudoinfinite `ViewPager` with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. I dynamically add `CalendarFragment`s into it. I have member variable `mUpdatedShiftsCont` what is connect point to another inner fragment:

**CalendarFragment.java:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle) {
  ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_fragment, container, false);
  mCalendarView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.calendar);
  mUpdatedShiftsCont = (FrameLayout)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_updated_shifts_container);

  return rootView;
}
```

**layout.calendar_fragment:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/calendar_fragment_id"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  ...

  <FrameLayout
     android:paddingTop="30dp"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:id="@+id/calendar_updated_shifts_container" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I try add inner fragment to connect point,

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
  .add(mUpdatedShiftsCont.getId(), fragment).commit();
```

all nested fragments are placed in one parent fragment in `ViewPager`:

[image]

Does anyone have idea how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to add or replace your inner fragment?

Comment: I want to add inner fragment to fragments in `ViewPager`.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723964/replace-fragment-inside-a-viewpager?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, I've read this before, but there isn't actually answer to my question.

Comment: what im trying to tell you just dont use add use replace getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
  .replace(mUpdatedShiftsCont.getId(), fragment).commit();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found where is problem. When I was adding inner fragment to fragment in `ViewPager`, I used method `mUpdatedShiftsCont.getId()` to get container ID. When I try to print containers' IDs in all `ViewPager`'s fragments I get this result:

```
Log.d("CF", "ID: " + String.valueOf(mUpdatedShiftsCont.getId()));

09-27 23:14:05.154    8388-8388/cz.skywall.sichtovnik_v2 D/CF: ID: 2131492885
09-27 23:14:05.170    8388-8388/cz.skywall.sichtovnik_v2 D/CF: ID: 2131492885
09-27 23:14:05.193    8388-8388/cz.skywall.sichtovnik_v2 D/CF: ID: 2131492885
09-27 23:14:05.225    8388-8388/cz.skywall.sichtovnik_v2 D/CF: ID: 2131492885
09-27 23:14:05.256    8388-8388/cz.skywall.sichtovnik_v2 D/CF: ID: 2131492885
```

So different containers (because different fragments) have same ID. **Solution:**

```
mUpdatedShiftsCont.setId(1000 + mCurrentMonth + mCurrentYear);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
  .add(1000 + mCurrentMonth + mCurrentYear, fragment).commit();
```

I have set new IDs based od fragment's content. They are now unique (probably) and It works as I want to.

Comment: If there's only a small number of finite fragments in your pager, you could define the IDs in your res/values folder and use those (to guarantee uniqueness).

Comment: Thanks for advice. Unfortunately I have o lot of fragments.

Comment: @skywall  you solve my problem, thanks!  Since I only have 4 fragment, so I follow @MH. suggestion to define IDs in `res/values/ids`.