# Switch fragment Fail inside viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My hierarchy is like this.A viewpager included 3 pages(all fragment),called 
`NewFragment`,`InvoledFragment` and `MeFragment`,and outside the viewpager i set a Radiobutton to switch between `Newfragment` and another fragment named `Hotfragment`,for some reason i used `hide(),show()`to manage the switch,here is![enter image description here is my code

[Page 1](http://112.124.56.38/1.jpg)

[Page 2](http://112.124.56.38/2.jpg)

[Page 3](http://112.124.56.38/3.jpg)

RadioButton check listener

```
private class CheckedChangeListener implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.button_new:
                mFragmentAtPos0 = newfrag;
                fragTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                if(!newfrag.isAdded()){
                    fragTransaction.hide(hotfrag).add(R.id.mainviewpager,newfrag).commit();
                }
                else{
                    fragTransaction.hide(hotfrag).show(newfrag).commit();
                }
                mFragmentAtPos0 = newfrag;


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NEW", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.button_hot:

                fragTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                if(!hotfrag.isAdded()){
                    fragTransaction.hide(newfrag).add(R.id.mainviewpager,hotfrag).commit();
                }
                else{
                    fragTransaction.hide(newfrag).show(hotfrag).commit();
                }
                mFragmentAtPos0 = hotfrag;


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "HOT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

and the FragmentPagerAdapter

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    public MyPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mFragmentManager = fm;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0){
            Log.d("check","111");
            return mFragmentAtPos0;
        }
        else if(position == 1){
            return(new InvolveFragment());
        }
        else {
            return(new MeFragment());
        }

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object)
    {
    if (object instanceof NewFragment && mFragmentAtPos0 == hotfrag)
        return POSITION_NONE;
    return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
    }
}
```

My problem is the `HotFrag` didn't show,but it worked (I put log code in hotfrag to check),and viewpager just works fine,I stucked here for several hours but still got no way to solve it.

There is a answer i found quite similar,it's here
[Replace Fragment inside a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723964/replace-fragment-inside-a-viewpager), but i worked with hide,show, not replace.

Anyone could help?Thanks a lot!