# Fragment <MyFragment> is not currently in the FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to replace a fragment inside a `ViewPager` and this is the code I use:-

```
mPagerAdapter.startUpdate(mPager);
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction().setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
    .remove(old_fragment)
    .add(mPager.getId(), Plain.newInstance(0)) //Plain.newInstance(int) returns a Fragm
    .commit();
mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(mPager);
```

and I get this error:- 
`Fragment <MyFragment> is not currently in the FragmentManager`

Comment: Does the error message refer to **old_fragment**?

Comment: @helleye yes it refers to the old fragment

Comment: Then maybe you should check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9127423/2160877