# Add fragment in fragment from ViewPager

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a ViewPager with fragments. I want to add a new fragment in the first and added back button in the ActionBar. If you can offer me the idea to realization. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean 'add a new fragment in the first'? In the viewPager?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723964/replace-fragment-inside-a-viewpager/13925130#13925130

Comment: And then the back button is: Activity.getActionBar().setHomeAsUpEnabled(true); Activity.getActionBar().setIcon(a back icon), and override Activity.onBackPressed.

Comment: Thanks, guys! I solved my problem with link from @DanielNugent