# How to replace current fragment in a tabbed activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I used the wizard to create an tabbed Activity which contains an FragmentPagerAdapter, in the getItem() function I returned my own fragments as follows: 
[image: 3 Tabs]
and I put an button in the class **BlankFragment**, in its onClickListener I tried to open **BlankFragment3** as follows, 
[image: redirect to BlankFragment3]
but it stops running and says:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0068
>   (com.drunkpiano.fragmentlast:id/container) for fragment
>   BlankFragment3{2a5d6e3b #0 id=0x7f0c0068}

Why? Is it because the container of replace() is for the whole 3 fragments including the tabs bar?

> ```
> <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
>     android:id="@+id/container"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
> ```

Comment: You need `FrameLayout` with id `container` in `fragment_blank`

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723964/replace-fragment-inside-a-viewpager