# Reload data on tab selected in a fragment using view pager

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin

I have my fragments inside view page but I would like to reload the data on the tab selected.I tried returning `PositionNone` in the `GetItemPosition` method in my `FragmentPagerAdapter` but it does not work.

I tried adding `notifyDataSetChanged();` on tab selected but it throws nullpointer exception.
I even tried setting the `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit` 
I managed to find the link :
[Replace Fragment inside a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723964/replace-fragment-inside-a-viewpager)
but it is on java. 
I have managed to convert most of the code to c# but gets stuck on the commented code. I am not sure how to call the  listener and instantiate the class at the same time? There is a lot of similar question but unfortunately not one in Xamarin Android.

I need to do this in xamarin android. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This is my FragmentAdapter

```
public class TabsFragmentPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private readonly Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment[] fragments;
    static readonly int NUM_ITEMS = 2;
    private readonly Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager FragmentManager;
    private Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment mFragmentAtPos0;
    private readonly ICharSequence[] titles;

    public TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fm, Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment[] fragments, ICharSequence[] titles) : base(fm)
    {
        this.fragments = fragments;
        this.titles = titles;

    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return fragments.Length;
        }
    }

    public override int GetItemPosition(Java.Lang.Object objectValue)
    {
        if (objectValue.GetType() == typeof(startJobFrag) && mFragmentAtPos0.GetType() == typeof(jobCaptureFrag))
        {
            return PositionNone;
        }
        return PositionUnchanged;
    }


    public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
    {
        return titles[position];
    }


    public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
    {
        if (position == 0)
        {
            if (mFragmentAtPos0 == null)
            {
                //not working
            }
            return mFragmentAtPos0;
        }
        else
        {
            return new jobCaptureFrag();
        }
    }
```

This is my Actvity

```
 void FnInitTabLayout()
    {
        var fragments = new Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment[]
        {
new frag 1(),
new frag 2(),
new frag 3(),
        };

        //Tab title array
        var titles = CharSequence.ArrayFromStringArray(new[] {
    "Page 1",
    "Page 2",
     "Page 3",
   });

        var viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
        //viewpager holding fragment array and tab title text
        //viewPager.
        viewPager.Adapter = new TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager, fragments, titles);

        // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager 
        tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        viewPager.PageSelected += (object sender, ViewPager.PageSelectedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            //FnInitTabLayout();
            if(e.Position == 0)
            {
              //handle tab click/selected

            }
        };
}

public interface FirstPageFragmentListener
{
    void onSwitchToNextFragment();
}
```

Fragment

```
public class Fragment1: Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{        
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);

        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.myview, container, false);

   }
}
```

Comment: don't know about xamairn but try to viewPage.setOffscreenPageLimit(0)

Comment: Hint: Inside your fragment, check if it is visibile. If it is, make call to load data.

Comment: @anstaendig I tried loading the data but got null exception

Comment: @AntonKazakov I tried setting it to 0 but it defaults back to 1

Comment: @anstaendig I think the fragment is on hold or something and the controls are not accessible at that time.When I load the data on tab selected, it like the view is not loaded yet. Any other ideas will be greatly appreciated

Comment: @ReaganGallant Can you provide the fragment code?

Comment: @anstaendig I have updated my question

Comment: @ReaganGallant Have you tried setting the page offset of the viewpager to the amount of tabs you have so you can make sure that all fragments get initialised right away? And the loading logic is not happening inside the fragment but somewhere else and you pass the data to the fragment?

Comment: @anstaendig I'm not sure what offset you are referring to. I tried setting the "setOffscreenPageLimit" but made no difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve it on my own.
In My activity I called `NotifyDataSetChanged()` on Pageselected event

**Activity**

```
  ViewPager.PageSelected += (object sender,                 ViewPager.PageSelectedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (e.Position == 1)
            {
                _pager.Adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
```

Then I changed my Adapter from `FragmentPagerAdapter` to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and override the `GetItemPosition`.

**Adapter**

```
    public class TabsFragmentPagerAdapter : FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    {
        public override int GetItemPosition(Java.Lang.Object objectValue)
        {
            return PositionNone;
        }
    }
```

**Refresh a specific tab** - inside the Adapter

```
 public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
    {
        if(position == 1) //second tab selected
        {
            NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }            
        return fragments[position];
    }
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do it but this works.

Comment: Is there a way to refresh one fragment only and not the entire viewpager?