# how to switch to second pager in a fragment by clicking on navigation drawer in android

Tags: android

I am new to android. I have a fragment with two pager, when i click on first item in navigation drawer it should open first pager in fragment and when i click second,it should open second pager in fragment.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9127423/4762282) can help you.

Comment: Try this link :  https://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/