# Unable to replace/navigate fragments

Tags: java, android, eclipse, user-interface, android-fragments

I am trying to navigate from one fragment to another. These two fragments are 100% different, there is no `ViewPager` or something like that to connect them. Here is the code.

**fragment_view1.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/firstView">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewOneText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="92dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="182dp"
        android:text="First View"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewOneBtn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/viewOneText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewOneText"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="Click Here" />

  <include layout = "@layout/drop_down"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


   <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**custom_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/customFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="174dp"
        android:text="Custom Fragment"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**FirstView.java** (uses fragment_view1.xml)

```
    package com.example.fragmenttest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FirstView extends DropDownMenu
{
    private TextView firstText;
    private Button btn;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view1,container,false);


        firstText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.viewOneText);
        btn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.viewOneBtn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new ButtonEvent());
        return view;

    }

    private class ButtonEvent implements OnClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // Create new fragment and transaction
            Fragment newFragment =  new CustomView();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_view, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }

    }


}
```

CustomView.java (uses custom_view.xml)

```
package com.example.fragmenttest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomView extends Fragment
{
    private TextView secondText;
    private Button secondViewBtn;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view,container,false);

        return view;

    }


}
```

In `FirstView.java`, when I click on the button, I need to move to the Fragment `CustomView`. But instead moving, it simply replaces everything in `CustomView` on top of `FirstView`. Below images will explain it better.

*`FirstView` alone*

[image]

*`CustomView` alone*

[image]

*When the button is `FirstView` clicked*

[image]

Why it is happening like this?

Comment: you need to exchange fragments inside FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to replace `firstView` with the new fragment, but `firstView` is not a fragment, its' a `RelativeLayout`.

You cannot replace a fragment defined statically in the layout file. You can only replace fragments that you added dynamically via a `FragmentTransaction`.

None of your Layout contains fragment in layout.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:layout_width="march_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></fragment>
```

A new Fragment will replace an existing Fragment that was previously added to the container.

Take look on [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html#usingfragments_fragmentmanager).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah I looked at it but didnt understand it. So what I have to do? code example? may be a modification to my demo code please?

Comment: Although you know, please revise how fragment works,(http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) change what you are looking for.

Comment: I edited the code. Please have a look at FirstView.java and fragment_view1.xml. The issue is still there

Comment: you have added `FrameLayout` in your Layout.xml file you need to add `fragment`. and one more important thing - you need to attach the first-View on the fragment initially and then on button onClick you need to replace it by the Custom fragment. Hope you got my point.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace one fragment with another then fallow undermentioned :

```
TalkDetail fragment = new TalkDetail(); 
// TalkDetail is name of fragment which you need to put while replacing older one.
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                    bundle.putString("title", m_ArrayList.get(arg2).title);
                    bundle.putString("largeimg", m_ArrayList.get(arg2).largeimg);
                    bundle.putString("excert", m_ArrayList.get(arg2).excert);
                    bundle.putString("description", m_ArrayList.get(arg2).description);
                    bundle.putString("cat", m_ArrayList.get(arg2).cat);
                    bundle.putString("header_title", "Talk");
                    //bundle.putInt("postid", m_ArrayList.get(arg2).postid);

                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);                  ((BaseContainerFragment)getParentFragment()).replaceFragment(fragment, true);
```

Here's your BaseContainerFragment.java class that will manage a lot of stuff for you.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import app.drugs.talksooner.R;

public class BaseContainerFragment extends Fragment {

    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.replace(R.id.container_framelayout, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
        getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }

    public boolean popFragment() {
        Log.e("test", "pop fragment: " + getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
        boolean isPop = false;
        if (getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            isPop = true;
            getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
        return isPop;
    }

}
```

For more specific details find my complete post over here ..

[Dynamically changing the fragments inside a fragment tab host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120510/dynamically-changing-the-fragments-inside-a-fragment-tab-host/19859871#19859871)